# Is there a makefile system for LaTeX, etc?

Tags: compiling, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)

How do I handle building complicated and large LaTeX projects?

Is there a makefile system (like GNU Make) or should I just write my own shell scripts (what I'm doing now)?

Answer (score 4):

[LaTeXMk](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=latexmk) is a Pearl script that is very intelligent about different TeX systems, whether or not you need `bibtex` or `mkindex` run, how many times to run it, etc.

Give it a shot!

Answer (score 2):

[rubber](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~beffara/soft/rubber/) is basically the `make` of LaTeX.

Comment: It's even better: it finds the dependencies automatically.