# Word-like colors for different versions of one file

Tags: packages, msword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good way to show changes between two versions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/what-is-a-good-way-to-show-changes-between-two-versions)

I was wondering if there is any package that can accomplish a Word-like color scheme for different versions of the same file.

So, if I have the `doc.tex` and then modify it to be `doc-v2.tex`. I can somehow tell the package in question that this file is actually a different (newer) version of `doc.tex`. And then it will put different color to the text that is new/modified in the `doc-v2.tex`. Just like Word does when you have different revisions.

Is there any package that does something like that? Or do I have to manually change the color for each and every line that is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [TrackChanges - Collaborative editing of LaTeX documents](http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/). From the website abstract:

> TrackChanges is a package for collaboratively editing LaTeX documents.
>   It allows multiple editors to make changes and add annotations to a
>   document. These changes and notes will be color coded by editor and
>   added to the compiled document. The TrackChanges GUI allows the author
>   to quickly find and accept, reject or modify the suggested edits.

All changes/modifications to the source file will have to be coded:

> `\note[editor]{The note}` 
>   `\annote[editor]{Text to annotate}{The note}` 
>   `\add[editor]{Text to add}` 
>   `\remove[editor]{Text to remove}` 
>   `\change[editor]{Text to remove}{Text to add}`

in a very similar manner to marking change in colour.

---

Alternatively, the [`latexdiff` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff) allows for similar style tracking of the difference between two sources.

Comment: Thanks, the latexdiff did the trick. I'm having hard time when the sections titles have changes, because it creates duplicated entries when I hide the deleted text. But I can live with that.