# Compare revisions of pdf

Tags: pdftex, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to track changes between PDFs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/how-to-track-changes-between-pdfs)

I use git to keep track of my LaTeX sourcefiles so I can compare and restore any state of my document.

My supervisor has given me an extensive list of how I should modify the text. I would like to know if there is an easy way of generating a new document where every changed section is highlighted so that during proofreading I can see which part I have to pay attention to.

Comment: This question on another stackexchange site may help you : http://askubuntu.com/questions/40813/diff-of-two-pdf-files

Comment: I want to generate a pdf file that shows the difference between the two source files.

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65453/track-changes-in-latex) or [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3757/what-is-a-good-way-to-show-changes-between-two-versions) help?