# Best practice for maintaining change history in tex

Tags: changes

Whenever I write a collaborative document, it undergoes a lot of draft changes. Apart from maintaining the change history in svn, how can I maintain the change history in the tex document itself? I also want it to reflect on the generated pdf.

Comment: Since you keeping the change history in svn, I would simply define a command `version` is that what you are looking for or are you looking for something to `diff`?

Comment: Probably you will need [changebar.sty][1] to mark the revision. 


  [1]: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/changebar/changebar.pdf

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff/

Comment: Any thing with the `revision-control` tag should be useful, such as the following questions:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161/latex-packages-for-use-with-revision-control
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/using-latexdiff-with-git

Comment: What exactly do you want? A list of changes somewhere in the document (eg in the appendix)? Highlighting changes directly in the document where they occur? If so, how many revision? Or do you only want to print a version number?

Comment: @Caramdir : A list of changes somewhere in the document like an appendix..this is in the generated pdf.

Comment: @Caramdir : actually, its better if we avoid os specific scripts.I prefer everything to be in the tex file as tex is pretty much a programming language rather than anything else

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want a revision history table showing the following four items, you should look at the [vhistory](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/vhistory) package.

- Version
- Date
- Authors
- Summary of the changes

If you're wanting the exact revision history from SVN, this might not be the package for you, as this revision history table is created in the LaTeX document. I find this advantageous since I want a more succinct revision history table than every little check-in to [git](http://git-scm.com).

### Example vhistory code

```
\usepackage{vhistory}
\begin{document}
% Start of the revision history table
\begin{versionhistory}
  \vhEntry{1.0}{22.01.04}{JPW|KW}{created}
  \vhEntry{1.1}{23.01.04}{DP|JPW}{correction}
  \vhEntry{1.2}{03.02.04}{DP|JPW}{revised after review}
\end{versionhistory}
```

Use the `tablegrid` option if you want to "display a grid in the table representing the revision history."

### Example vhistory output

[image]

Comment: `vhistory` is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 6):

I have previously used the `svninfo` Herbert already mentioned.

But I recently found the [`vc bundle`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/vc/). It has the advantage/difference of not only tracking the included `.tex` files but any file in the directory. You will get the global revision, including images or `.bib` files as well. Apart from svn it supports bzr and git.

On the other hand, it is an external shell-script and not a LaTeX package. Also you will only get the global revision number, not a more fine-grained result depending on current file etc. as `svninfo` provides.

Supplement: Since it does not use svn properties and special lines in the TeX file, it is completely independent from the `svninfo` approach and you can even combine both variants.

Comment: can vc also do the communication (up/download) with a repository? I didn't know it.

Comment: No. It basically just does a `svn info` and puts the resulting data into a tex command.

Comment: But then a combination of vc and svn seems to be possible?

Comment: @Herbert; Indeed. I just thought of that myself and added it.

Answer (score 4):

I Use package [rcs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/rcs.html) and put

```
\usepackage{rcs}
```

in the preamble. Then, lines such as:

```
\RCS $Id:$
\RCS $Source:$
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\RCSId}
```

put version information in the formated document.

I notice that there is also a package [rcsinfo](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/rcsinfo.html) with a similar purpose, but have not used it.

Comment: and also a package `svninfo`

Comment: and [`svn-multi`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/svn-multi.html) which supports multi-file documents.

Comment: and `gitinfo`...