# latexdiff is not working

Tags: latexdiff

I installed latexdiff to track changes. The first question is where to give the command (latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex). I saw on the internet that it can be done in the Command/DOS environment. But then I get the error that the file new.tex cannot be found in the directory. I have checked where the other packages are located which is downloaded and which are working. And I have downloaded Perl. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you're trying to run `latexdiff` in the correct directory (folder). Try typing `dir` on the command line, and see whether the `new.tex` file appears in the list somewhere.

Comment: @Martin, could you post your comment as an answer so that this question doesn't remain unanswered?

Comment: @Juan: Done, but feels a little like cheating..

Comment: @martin: you mean you'll get rep you feel you do not deserve? easy solution, call it CW.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to miss the `new.tex` file in your current directory. You can easily check whether it's present by running `dir` at the command line, and see whether the file appears in the output. You can always specify the full path to it, if necessary.

`latexdiff` is installed correctly and on your path (Perl as well), otherwise it would complain either about unknown command, or missing Perl interpreter.

A somewhat tangential note: Version control is almost mandatory if you're serious about using LaTeX for your writings.

Related questions:

- [Best practice for maintaining change history in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6560/best-practice-for-maintaining-change-history-in-tex)
- [LaTeX packages for use with revision control](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161/latex-packages-for-use-with-revision-control)
- [How can you use LaTeX to write a document with other people?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232/how-can-you-use-latex-to-write-a-document-with-other-people)

Comment: latexdiff is very usefull for working with people who don't grok computers....(like my old advisor...) that said, latexdiff is some serious difficulties when the changes are too big....