# Subversion keyword string inside LaTeX document

Tags: revision-control, subversion

I put a subversion keyword string inside my LaTeX document. It looks like:

```
$LastChangedDate: 2011-01-16 18:09:33 +0100 (nie) $
```

and it gets replaced (simple textual substitution) every time I make a commit to the repository. Also when I get an older version of the document, the date is also reverted to the time when that version was commited.

I wanted to make it look nicer in the output, so decided to make following definition:

```
\def\LastChangedDate: #1-#2-#3 #4:#5:#6 #7 (#8) {\year=#1\month=#2\day=#3\date{\today{} #4:#5}}
\newenvironment{subversionparse}{\catcode`$=0}{\catcode`$=3}

\begin{subversionparse}
$LastChangedDate: 2011-01-16 18:09:33 +0100 (nie) $
\end{subversionparse}
```

Firstly it defines `LastChangedDate` macro which parses the following text and sets the date as TeX "today" date, and then defines \date as "today" followed by time. This makes the output nicely localized, in my case: "16 stycznia 2011 18:09".

Then a new environment is made to temporarily change `$` character to escape character, so that `$LastChangedDate` gets parsed as real macro.

Now, I am happy that I managed to get this working. What potential problems do you see with this approach? Maybe there are other, simpler ways of doing the same thing?

Comment: For package solutions see [“LaTeX packages for use with revision control”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161/latex-packages-for-use-with-revision-control).

Comment: Accepting Ulrich's answer because it actually points out potential improvements. Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not manually re-set the catcode of `$` to 3, because you do not know if it was 3 in the first place. (At least, onlyamsmath and nag set `$` to active, and pgf does fancy stuff, too, though maybe pgf only does so locally.) Let the \endgroup take care of it: catcode assignments are local.

From memory, a safe way using delimited arguments should be:

```
\def\svnparse{\def\svnp@rse $##1${\svnp@rs@ #1\@nil}\svnp@rse}
```

with `\svnp@rs@` using delimited arguments similar to your code. The key is to redefine `\svnp@rse` at runtime, so you pick up the currently active catcode of `$` (unless we are in an argument already). The further indirection is just to make sure that third parties can still hook into or patch your commands.

BTW, ingenious use of resetting the escape char! Tip of the hat to you!

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can try `svn` (or `svn-multi`, `svn-info`, etc.) package.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/svn.html

Answer (score 6):

You can do the same using my "[svn-multi](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/svn-multi.html)" package:

```
\svnid{$Id$}
\date{\svntoday \svnhour:\svnminute}
```

It does all the catcode magic for you and also works with multiple source files, e.g. include files.

Answer (score 4):

The [vc bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/vc/) has a neat way to include revision information like this. And since the formatting is done by an `awk` script, it's easy to manipulate it into giving you custom formats and so on.