# Is it possible to have an undetermined character length argument in a macro?

Tags: macros, latexdiff

I have the following macro,

```
\def\RCS$ $#1: #2 $ ${\expandafter\def\csname RCS#1\endcsname{#2}}
```

Which is used for revision version control, i.e,

```
\RCS$ $Revision: 1.2 $ $
\RCS$ $Date: 2010/04/02 18:20:00 $ $
\lhead{Revision \RCSRevision, \RCSDate}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Which works great. However if I then use latexdiff on it with another revision, the diff file doesn't expand the macro correctly,

```
\RCS$ $Revision: \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{1.2 }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{1.8 }\DIFaddend $ $
```

Is there a way to get it to expand the second argument as a single text block?

(This relates to my question [Can latexdiff-cvs handle RCS tags?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33524/can-latexdiff-cvs-handle-rcs-tags))

Answer (score 3):

**Total Edit:** Effectively, you want `\edef`, which totally expands its contents before defining a macro.  However, there is a hitch: `latexdiff` defines `\DIFadd` and `\DIFend` to print something involving colors, which is not really good material for parsing as text like you want to do.  On top of that, it is careful enough to `\protect` them, and the whole point of `\protect` is to interfere with normal expansion.  So trying to use `\edef` directly will give you an error (apparently, "TeX capacity exceeded").

What I do, then, is temporarily redefine these two macros to do what they "logically" do: include or ignore their contents.  Since that shouldn't be a permanent change, I do it in a group, and this necessitates that I use `\xdef`, the global version of `\edef`.

The way this little program works is that it grabs the material between dollar signs like your `\RCS` does, but then feeds it to `\edef` to produce an expanded text `\expandedRCS`.  It then places the contents of `\expandedRCS` after another macro, `\innerRCS`, that does what your `\RCS` used to.  `\expandedRCS` is created in a group as explained above, but once it is defined I no longer need the new definitions of `\DIFadd` and `\DIFend`, so I can (and should) expand `\innerRCS` *outside* the group.

Here is a complete document.  I've included the `latexdiff` preamble for verisimilitude.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\RCS$ $#1$ ${%
 {%
  \renewcommand{\DIFadd}[1]{##1}%
  \renewcommand{\DIFdel}[1]{}%
  \xdef\expandedRCS{#1}%
 }%
 \expandafter\innerRCS\expandedRCS
}
\def\innerRCS#1: #2 {\expandafter\def\csname RCS#1\endcsname{#2}}

%DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}
\RCS$ $Revision: \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{1.2 }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{1.8 }\DIFaddend $ $
Revision \RCSRevision.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is the "regular expression" part of defining the macro. Specifically, how to match what comes after the first argument. In this case, I want #2 to be all of `\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{1.2 }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{1.8 }\DIFaddend`. Is there a way I can change the macro definition to accommodate this?

Comment: @Shaun: I don't use latexdiff-cvs, so I don't know exactly what you are after, but I have made a revision based on what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. But this doesn't seem to work for me - something about running out of memory. Isn't the `\edef\expandedRCS{#1}\expandafter\innerRCS\expandedRCS` part recursively using `\expandedRCS`?

Comment: @Shaun: No, it doesn't expand recursively because `\expandedRCS` is set to `#1`; the `\expandafter` just places whatever `#1` expanded to after `\innerRCS`.  Your problem is actually that, in reality, the `\DIFadd` macro expands to something unexpandable (the `\protect` macro, whose point is to obstruct expansion).  The reason it's there is that `\DIFadd` is set to print its argument in color, and this is not a macro-expansion-level thing, but a lowlevel command.  Let me take a stab at correcting this.

Comment: Hi @Ryan thanks again. But I think I might have failed to explain what my end goal was. I want two things 1) to define a macro that can parse RCS tags (e.g Revision, Date, Author, etc) so that they can be used in text. I.e. if the date tag is `$Date: 2010/04/02 18:20:00 $` then I want `\RCSDate` to print `2010/04/02 18:20:00` in the text. I know how to achieve this, but I don't know how to combine it with the second thing I want - 2) I want the RCS tags to print BOTH rcs tags (before and after replacement) like latexdiff does with other text changes (i.e red strikethrough and blue underline)

Comment: I.e., `\def\RCSRevision{\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{1.2 }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{1.8 }\DIFaddend}
Revision \RCSRevision.`