# How to add a version counter to a document in LaTeX?

Tags: koma-script, automation

Well this can be a silly question, but now I begin to give copies of my thesis for review, I would like to add a counter versions of the document. Then I have curious if there are any package or some example code that allows to add that to my thesis.

I know I could manually add a line on a page and put any `version x`, but will there way to automate it? I already checked the `version`  and `versions` packages in the CTAN, but it is not what I want.

I think this question does not require an MWE, if ever serve say that I'm using the `scrbook` class. Otherwise I upload a MWE later.

---

### Update

Well this could be a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=8,headsepline=true]{scrbook}    
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[single=false,macros=false,xspace=false]{acro}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,empheq,bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}    

%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} %[markcase=ignoreuppercase]
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

\usepackage{graphicx,subfig,etex,tikz,pgfplots,afterpage}
\graphicspath{{./imagen/}}    

\usepackage{snotez}

\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=1000

\KOMAoption{parskip}{half*}
\setparsizes{1em}{0.25\baselineskip plus .25\baselineskip}{1em plus 1fil}

\renewcommand*{\dictumwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\upshape}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\extratitle{{\large Thesis title}\\ thesis subtitle}
\titlehead{{\LARGE My University} 

\medskip

{\Large My Faculty}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\\ 
{\large Engineering}}
\subject{Thesis}
\title{Thesis title}
\subtitle{Tehsis subtitle}
\author{Aradnix Veckhom\thanks{IIMAS} \\{\normalsize Account number: 09804642-5}}
\date{Universitary City \today}
\publishers{Advisor:\\ \begin{normalsize} Dr. Evil\footnotemark[1]\footnote{De facto}\\
        Dr. Mono\footnotemark[1]\footnote{De jure}
\end{normalsize}}

\lowertitleback{La composición tipográfica se llevó a cabo con la ayuda de {\KOMAScript} empleando el sistema \LaTeXe{} de Leslie Lamport con los paquetes \AmS{}; basado a su vez en \TeX{} versión 3.141592 de Donald Knuth; con las familias Mathpazo (Extensión de Palatino diseñada por Hermann Zapf), y Textcomp, en cuerpos de 8/14, 10/14, 11/14, 16/19, 21/25 y 26/31 puntos de pica tradicional.} 

\uppertitleback{\copyright{} 2014 Araden\u{a}torix Veckh\^{o}m Vacel\ae{}vus \\ Diseño y composición: \emph{Listopad}\\
Versión $\beta 1.0$ } 
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

As you could see I add a line with a version name manually. I simply want to know if it could be automated in someway without need a VCS. That's all.

Comment: check out [`gitinfo2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo2)

Comment: Have you seen [LaTeX packages for use with revision control](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161) ?

Comment: [Add a version number to the title of a LaTeX document](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5226754) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: In any case, if an answer is not already covered elsewhere, we'd need to know which version control system you use.

Comment: @PaulGessler *if* a VCS is being used.

Comment: `\fancyfoot[C]{\today}` worked for me...

Comment: An MWE might not be strictly needed to understand your question, but not providing one requires potential answerers to create one in order to demonstrate any solution.

Comment: I use `svn-multi`.

Comment: @SeanAllred Nice and interesting package, thanks.

Comment: @PaulGessler not yet but thanks for the suggestion. In fact I use git, but not with this project. My thesis advisors have no idea about what is a version control system nor willingness to learn, so don't go out there my doubt. It was a much more pedestrian question.

Comment: @JJoao Thanks, good idea but KOMA Script has its own package for this instead of `fancyhdr`. I could find an equivalent for the trick you suggest.

Comment: Then why have you tagged it [tag:revision-control]? This tag is for using TeX with VCSs.

Comment: You don't need version control for your _thesis advisors_ you need it for _you_ :-)

Comment: There is not a unique solution. I would like to see an answer summarizing the basic ideas (and accepting comments/contributions).

Comment: @PaulGessler Because I was in a hurry and it was a mistake.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, but that version number is what I use with them.

Comment: You probably are not generating three different versions per day, so i think to put the current date (`\today`) to the footer will be completely sufficient to keep track of the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I would do it "half automate".  I mean to build a mechanismn to take over the versions number of a tool like subversion or so I would not do.  It is not interesting how many times I changed/saved my code (that could be 10 times a day or more), the intersting thing a numbering of the versions your professor gets (of course it is then a good idea to save the posted versions on your computer, too).

So I simply create a new command `\myscriptversion` in the main `tex` file containing a versions number and the printing date like:

```
\newcommand{\myscriptversion}{Versi{\`o}n $\beta 1.0$, \today}
```

Now you can use this new command to add the version on every place you need it, for example on the title page or (IMHO better) in the footer:

```
\ifoot{\myscriptversion}% add version to foot line of each page
\uppertitleback{\copyright{} 2014 Araden\u{a}torix Veckh\^{o}m Vacel\ae{}vus \\ 
  Diseño y composición: \emph{Listopad}\\
  \myscriptversion}
```

Your changed code (I added `blindtext` to be able to see the footer of a normal page; changes see `< ===========` marks):

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=10pt,
  paper=letter,
  headings=big,
  bibliography=totoc,
  DIV=8,
  headsepline=true
]{scrbook}

\newcommand{\myscriptversion}{Versi{\`o}n $\beta 1.0$, \today} % <======
\usepackage{blindtext}  % <=============================================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}    

\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} %[markcase=ignoreuppercase]
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\ifoot{\myscriptversion} % <===========================================
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=1000

\KOMAoption{parskip}{half*}
\setparsizes{1em}{0.25\baselineskip plus .25\baselineskip}{1em plus 1fil}

\renewcommand*{\dictumwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\upshape}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\extratitle{{\large Thesis title}\\ thesis subtitle}
\titlehead{{\LARGE My University} 

\medskip

{\Large My Faculty}\\
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\\ 
{\large Engineering}}

\subject{Thesis}
\title{Thesis title}
\subtitle{Tehsis subtitle}
\author{Aradnix Veckhom\thanks{IIMAS} \\{\normalsize Account number: 09804642-5}}
\date{Universitary City \today}
\publishers{Advisor:\\ \begin{normalsize} Dr. Evil\footnotemark[1]\footnote{De facto}\\
        Dr. Mono\footnotemark[1]\footnote{De jure}
\end{normalsize}}

\lowertitleback{La composición tipográfica se llevó a cabo con la ayuda de {\KOMAScript} empleando el sistema \LaTeXe{} de Leslie Lamport con los paquetes \AmS{}; basado a su vez en \TeX{} versión 3.141592 de Donald Knuth; con las familias Mathpazo (Extensión de Palatino diseñada por Hermann Zapf), y Textcomp, en cuerpos de 8/14, 10/14, 11/14, 16/19, 21/25 y 26/31 puntos de pica tradicional.} 

\uppertitleback{\copyright{} 2014 Araden\u{a}torix Veckh\^{o}m Vacel\ae{}vus \\ 
  Diseño y composición: \emph{Listopad}\\
  \myscriptversion}  % <================================================
\maketitle

\mainmatter      % <====================================================
\Blinddocument   % <====================================================

\end{document}
```