# How to make Latexmk use makeglossaries?

Tags: compiling, tools, glossaries, automation, latexmk

Is there a way to make [Latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) invoke `makeglossaries` (part of the [glossaries](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/) package)?

Specifically I want to use latexmk to compile a LaTeX document that uses the `glossaries` package to produce a glossary.  Currently I'm using this rather clumsy sequence of commands:

```
makeglossaries document
latexmk -pdf document.tex
makeglossaries document
latexmk -pdf document.tex
```

The first run of makeglossaries is required to produce files that the `glossaries` package needs, or otherwise causes latexmk to fail, but there's still no data in the (non-existant) .aux file, so that first makeglossaries invocation produces nothing (except for an empty file).

So, how to do this using latexmk alone (and let that deal with invoking makeglossaries at the right time)?

Comment: People finding this, maybe read [one of the newer answers from 2020](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541990/43012) which does not have so many votes yet.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to write a configuration file that tells latexmk which files are interesting for the glossary and how to handle them. Fortunately, the author provides some [sample rc files](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles).

Putting

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
sub makeglo2gls {
    system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.glg -o '$_[0]'.gls '$_[0]'.glo");
}
```

in `~/.latexmkrc` (globally in your home directory) or `./latexmkrc` (locally in your document directory) should do the trick.

Comment: Do you have to add something to your build command?

Comment: Also, why does it go into directory `.latexmkrc/latexmkrc`? I thought it was simply the `.latexmkrc` or `latexmkrc` file?

Comment: @drozzy: It’s the file `.latexmkrc` or `latexmkrc` in the directory where the LaTeX master file you are working on resides.

Comment: The link is broken, here is the official mirror: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles

Comment: The answer is about makeindex not about glossaries package. Is this correct?

Comment: Since your answer is accepted, could you update it to actually include the contents of `glossary_latexmkrc ` file? Yours doesn't make acronyms.

Answer (score 101):

At Hans-Peter E. Kristiansen’s request, I provide another answer, extending the one given by kay102.

Add the following lines to some `latexmk` initialization file (e.g., on Linux systems, `~/.latexmkrc`):

```perl
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
    my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] ); #handle -outdir param by splitting path and file, ...
    pushd $path; # ... cd-ing into folder first, then running makeglossaries ...

    if ( $silent ) {
        system "makeglossaries -q '$base_name'"; #unix
        # system "makeglossaries", "-q", "$base_name"; #windows
    }
    else {
        system "makeglossaries '$base_name'"; #unix
        # system "makeglossaries", "$base_name"; #windows
    };

    popd; # ... and cd-ing back again
}
```

As a consequence, if `latexmk` is invoked with the `-silent` option `makeglossaries` will be silent, too.

Moreover, add

```perl
push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

to update the cleanup functionality of `latexmk` appropriately.

Comment: Cool - I am assuming that you find that kay102's answer is the best(however marginal). Can you improve this answer by adding extension from glossaries to remove with the -c or -C option? or is this bad for some reason?

Comment: @Hans-Peter E. Kristiansen: I’ve extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed. Bounty coming up when grace period is over.

Comment: Now the only file(except `.tex`) that is not removed by -C option, is the `.bbl` file. Should I add `push @generated_exts, 'bbl';` or `$clean_ext .= ' %R.bbl';` to my `latexmkrc`?

Comment: @Hans-Peter E. Kristiansen: The `.bbl` file isn’t related to the `glossaries` package. So it could be worth posing your comment as a regular question. (Most probably, you need `$bibtex_use = 2;`.)

Comment: On Windows, with MikTeX or TeXLive, the two commands should be `system "makeglossaries", "-q", $_[0];` and  `system "makeglossaries", $_[0];`...

Comment: I don't know why your answer make my cross reference (`\ref`,`\cite`) not work, but @caramdir's answer works perfect for me.

Comment: Is it possible to add comments to the `latexmkrc` file? Should they be preceded by `%` or `#`? I just want to reference this url in my `latexmkrc` file. Thanks.

Comment: Like @PaulGaborit said, the window-specific version should not have the single quotes around $_[0].  Is there a way to have a if-then-else condition to detect platform and apply the rule accordingly without further manual intervention?

Comment: What is the file name on Windows and where do I find it?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen It's `#`.

Answer (score 16):

You can also let latexmk call makeglossaries directly by adding the following to your latexmkrc file (in my case I had to add it to $HOME/.latexmkrc):

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries');

sub makeglossaries {
    system "makeglossaries $_[0]";
    if ( -z "$_[0].glo" ) {
        open GLS, ">$_[0].gls";
        close GLS;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With the current version of the `makeglossaries` program, testing for empty `.glo` and `.acn` files isn’t necessary any longer.

Comment: But this seems to be the only working solution for older `makeglossaries` versions and empty `.glo`s ...

Answer (score 12):

A lightweight solution is adding

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
sub makeglo2gls {
        system("makeglossaries $_[0]");
}
```

to your .latexmk file.

Comment: Slight improvement to the `makeglo2gls` subroutine: Call `makeglossaries` with/without the `-q` option, depending on whether `$silent` is true/false.

Comment: I'm trying to use this  to make a  list of acronyms but it is not working? Any ideas?

Comment: @kay102: Is your solution better than the others?

Comment: @mhp: Can you make a version with this improvement implemented? -I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @Hans-Peter E. Kristiansen: Done.

Answer (score 12):

My sources and generated files are in separated directories. Running mhp's solution I got the error: (require "doc.xdy") ERROR: Could not find file "doc.xdy". Then I extended the solution to:

```perl
file: conf/glossaries.latexmk
-----------------------------
print("LATEXMK: Glossaries Módule...\n");

use File::Basename;

add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
   $dir = dirname($_[0]);
   $file = basename($_[0]);
   if ( $silent ) {
      system "makeglossaries -q -d '$dir' '$file'";
   }
   else {
      system "makeglossaries -d '$dir' '$file'";
   };
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

Then I run as:

```
cd src
latexmk \
  -f -pdf -bibtex-cond \
  -r "../conf/glossaries.latexmk" \
  -auxdir=../.build -outdir=../.build \
  -pdflatex="xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S" doc
```

Comment: What does this do? `-r "../conf/glossaries.latexmk"`?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Specifies the configuration to throw to `latexmk`. In this case he is not using the system-wide settings but rather specific settings for this particular project / document / whatever.

Comment: This works if your auxiliary files are within a different directory, which was my original problem.

Answer (score 10):

The current version of the `glossary`/`glossaries` sample `latexmkrc` file on CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/glossaries_latexmkrc contains

```
# This shows how to use the glossaries package
# (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) and the glossaries-extra package
# (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) with latexmk.

# N.B. There is also the OBSOLETE glossary package
# (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossary), which has some differences.  See item 2.

# 1. If you use the glossaries or the glossaries-extra package, then you can use:

   add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
   add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
   $clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";

   sub makeglossaries {
        my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
        my @args = ( "-q", "-d", $path, $base_name );
        if ($silent) { unshift @args, "-q"; }
        return system "makeglossaries", "-d", $path, $base_name; 
    }

# 2. The above will tend to run makeglossaries more often than needed, since
#    each out of date file will trigger the use of makeglossaries, even
#    though makeglossaries makes all the glossaries.  The following solution
#    solves this, but at the expense of not having the convenience that
#    makeglossaries can change how it makes the glossaries depending on the
#    settings of the glossaries package.
#    A better solution will need more advanced work.
#
#   add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
#   add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
#   $clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";
#
#   sub makeglossaries {
#       my @args = ( "-s", "$_[0].ist", "-t", "$$Psource.ilg",
#                    "-o", $$Pdest, $$Psource );
#       if ($silent) { unshift @args, "-q"; }
#       return system "makeindex", @args;
#   }
```

However, the `makeglossaries` subroutine from the `glossaries_latexmkrc` example is flawed.

1. The initial definition of `@args`, in line two, should not contain `-q`, since it is added to `@args` in line 3 via `unshift` iff `$silent`.
2. The `@args` array is not used in the final line of the subroutine

A corrected version of the `makeglossaries` is

```perl
sub makeglossaries {
     my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
     my @args = ( "-d", $path, $base_name );
     if ($silent) { unshift @args, "-q"; }
     return system "makeglossaries", @args;
}
```

---

There was an older `glossary_latexmkrc` that read

```
add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
$clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";
sub makeglossaries {
  my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
  pushd $path;
  my $return = system "makeglossaries", $base_name;
  popd;
  return $return;
}
```

This also resolves the quoting issues on Windows mentioned (and resolved) in [Oliver](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26725/oliver)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149758/35864) for me.

Comment: Yes the sample worked right away for me as well (the other suggestions did not).

Comment: I use VS Code. I named this file `.latexmkrc` and put it into the same folder as the main TeX file. Voilá, the glossaries are there. Thanks for citing official documentation.

Comment: I also needed to install `xindy`, `sudo apt install xindy`.

Comment: The more I look at the perl code, the more I believe it is wrong. The first `"-q"` in line two of the `makeglossaries` subroutine should be removed, it is added in line three if `$silent` by `unshift`. Secondly, `@args` is not used in line four, when I think it should.

Comment: @Flow That's probably something you want to contact the `latexmk` maintainer about.

Answer (score 5):

mhp's code didn't work out for me on my windows 8 machine, so i changed his code to:

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q $_[0]";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries $_[0]";
  };
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

primarily i just removed the single quotes around `$_[0]`. otherwise `makeglossaries` wasn't able to find the `filename.aux` file properly.

Comment: This is true on Windows 10 as of Dec 2018 and the top voted answer must reflect this.