# List of Acronyms is not displayed

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossary
\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}
\newacronym{wasn}{WASN}{Wireless Sensor Networks}
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\newpage
using \gls{svm} blah blah \gls{wasn}blah blah.....\gls{svm}
\end{document}
```

I am testing with above MWE. The acronyms are correctly displayed in the document body when compiled, but nothing gets printed where I need the List of Acronyms. 
I am using TexMakerX as my IDE on Windows 7.

Once I compile the above code a `.glo` file is created but it is empty. I think this is the problem but I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Are you running `makeglossaries` in your document?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes

Comment: Your example works fine here, compiling with `pdflatex`, then `makeglossaries`, then `pdflatex` again.

Comment: An empty `.glo` file is not relevant here since you are working with acronyms. Check the file `.acr`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina no .acr is created but there is a .acn with content \glossaryentry{SVM?\glossaryentryfield{svm}{\glsnamefont{SVM}}{Support Vector Machine}{\relax }|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
\glossaryentry{WASN?\glossaryentryfield{wasn}{\glsnamefont{WASN}}{Wireless Sensor Networks}{\relax }|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
\glossaryentry{SVM?\glossaryentryfield{svm}{\glsnamefont{SVM}}{Support Vector Machine}{\relax }|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I understand when you say "compilling with pdflatex". How can I **run** makeglossaries? I just have that line in the document.

Comment: [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099) This is for Texmaker, but it is somewhat similar for TexmakerX. (Also, note that TexmakerX switched name to TeXStudio some time ago, so you're using a fairly old version of the software. That isn't really a problem, I'm just mentioning it in passing.)

Comment: You need to use `\makeglossaries` not `\makeglossary`

Comment: (The above's not the cause of the problem. It's more reliable).  You need to invoke the `makeglossaries` Perl script between your pdflatex runs. I've written an article on it on the [LaTeX Community Forum](http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms) and also in [a section of one of my LaTeX books](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/makeglossaries.html) on how to do that.

Answer (score 11):

Creating a list of acronyms (or glossary) is a three stage process (at least):

1. Typeset the document using LaTeX (or PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, as appropriate)
2. Run the `makeglossaries` Perl script or the `makeglossaries-lite` Lua script.
3. Typeset the document again.

(You may need to repeat step 3.) Every time you modify the document in a way that alters the list (for example, adding or deleting instances of `\gls`, or removing or inserting text that results in a change in the associated page numbers) then you need to repeat all three steps in order to update the list.

The command `\makeglossaries` in your document creates some glossary-related files (`.glo` or `.acn`) and each time you use commands like `\gls` an entry is added to the relevant file when the document is typeset (in step 1).

In step 2 a special indexing application is run that reads in those glossary-related files and writes another file (`.gls` or `.acr`) with the LaTeX code required to typeset the glossary or list of acronyms. This file is then input in your document in step 3.

Step 2 causes the most confusion as it requires running a [command line](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/terminal.html) script. However, most front-ends have a button or menu item you can click that will run the script for you. Most front-ends need to be configured to run `makeglossaries` or `makeglossaries-lite`. The following TeX.SE answers provide instructions for integrating `makeglossaries` on various front-ends.

- TeXMaker: [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61099/using-texmaker-with-glossaries-on-windows).
- TeXworks: [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152)
- TeXShop: [Adding a new engine in TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376649).

For WinEdt, have a look at the comp.text.tex thread [Executing Glossaries' makeindex from a WinEdt macro](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/comp.text.tex/7dg4MbgbB1k).

For other front-ends, see [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries/).

In each of the above cases, you need to have [Perl](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/perl.html) installed if you use `makeglossaries` (but not `makeglossaries-lite`) or if you want to use `xindy` instead of the default `makeindex`.

Since `makeglossaries-lite` is a Lua script, you should already have a Lua interpreter if you have a modern TeX distribution with LuaTeX. If you want to use `makeglossaries-lite` instead, you should just be able to replace all references to `makeglossaries` with `makeglossaries-lite`, although it has fewer options and doesn't provide diagnostic tools, so it's not as useful if things go wrong. (Note that `makeglossaries-lite` was added to `glossaries` version **4.16**, so it won't be available for older versions.)

Another possibility if you are having difficulty with step 2 is to add the package option `automake` to `glossaries`:

```
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
```

(Introduced in `glossaries` version **4.08**.) This will try to get TeX to run the external applications (step 3 is still required) but this won't work if the shell escape is disabled. This option also won't work with `xindy` in the restricted mode, since `xindy` isn't on the list of trusted applications.¹ With both `xindy` and `automake`, you would need the less secure unrestricted mode, which I don't recommend for security reasons.

Alternatively, there's [a GUI approach](http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms#makeglossariesgui) that uses Java rather than Perl. See also [What can interfere with glossaries to prevent printing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309233)

---

¹This is the case with TeX Live. I don't know about MiKTeX.

Comment: To accomplish this in WinEdt, you can simply go to `Options -> Execution Modes` and change the definition of `MakeGlossary` to `Executable:makeglossaries.exe`, `Switches:`, `Parameters:"%N"`. Now executing the command `MakeGlossary` you have what you want and executing `PDFTeXify` you obtain the full cycle `pdflatex - makeglossaries - pdflatex` as many times as needed for a full compilation.

Comment: I had a problem that glossary is not updated in pdf once I compile. But after I add '[automake]' in the 'usepackage' section not it's work well fine. Now it looks like this. '\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronym,section,automake]{glossaries}'

Answer (score 8):

Your MWE can be compiled even without the need of `makeglossaries` application (and so without the need of having Perl installed), exploiting `makeindex`.

In fact, running

1. `pdflatex <yourfile>`
2. `makeindex.exe -s <yourfile>.ist -o <yourfile>.acr <yourfile>.acn`
3. `pdflatex <yourfile>`
4. `pdflatex <yourfile>`

works the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an answer that worked for me, since there appears to be no accepted answer to this question and this question was the first one to pop up in a web-search.

The [glossaries package documentation](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf) states the following about using Hyperref:

> Take care if you use the glossaries package with hyperref. Contrary to the usual advice that hyperref should be loaded last, **glossaries (and glossaries-extra) must be loaded after hyperref**.

and the following about displaying entries:

> 1. Add `\makenoidxglossaries` to your preamble (before you start defining your entries, as described in Section 2).
> 2. Put: `\printnoidxglossary[sort=〈order〉,〈other options〉]` where you want your list of entries to appear.  Alternatively, use `\printnoidxglossaries`

Following these instructions resolved the issue for me.

**Note**: I'm using Overleaf so I have no control over package versions. They seem to use package version v4.41+. Which is why this works for me. I cannot confirm if this works for lower version numbers.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thanks for your answer and help. Could you add an minimal working example and your compiling commands?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is an alternative approach that can work for some, but be aware that the `\makenoidxglossaries` method [has a lot of drawbacks](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) and [can be very slow for large documents](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-performance.shtml#table1), so this solution may not work for everyone.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I'd love to do so. However, I'm busy writing my Master's Thesis. About the compiling commands. I'm using Overleaf and I have no clue what commands they use.

Answer (score 0):

I am also an overleaf user, and had a similar issue. I find Byebye's answer useful.

An alternative to using `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossary` is adding option 'automake', which worked for me: `\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}` (preamble) + `\makeglossaries` (preamble) + `\printglossaries` (where you want to print glossary).