# Not getting acronyms list displayed separately in latex document while the same code works fine in overleaf (online latex platform)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

This following code is giving me the output without displaying the list of acronyms.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries


\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}


\begin{document}
\noindent
First use \gls{cd}\\
subsequent \gls{cd}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

```
First use compact disk (CD)
subsequent CD
```

Can someone please help me identify the issue? The same code works fine in overleaf. Probably some issue with installed glossaries package but not sure.

Comment: If you think it is the `glossaries` package why not check the version with `\listfiles`

Comment: Package version is:
Package: glossaries 2018/05/10 v4.38 (NLCT)
I am unable to figure out the problem!

Comment: this version is it on overleaf or the other way you generate it?

Comment: Overleaf automatically runs `makeindex`. (I don't know whether it does it explicitly or via `makeglossaries`.) When you're not using Overleaf, you need to include `makeglossaries` in your document build process. See, for example, [List of Acronyms is not displayed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110095), [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152) and [Using Texmaker with glossaries on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61099)