# No acronyms printed

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

This is my main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\input{acronymes.tex}
\input{glossary.tex}

\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}
\sffamily
 The  typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrshort{gcd}, 

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \printnoidxglossary[nonumberlist]
    \printglossary


\end{document}
```

The content of acronymes.tex is:

```
\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
```

And the one of glossary.tex

```
\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=maths,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}
```

This is based on [this example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries).

But for me, there is no acronym printed : [image]

What do I do wrong? I've already tried this: [List of Acronyms is not displayed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110095/list-of-acronyms-is-not-displayed)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `\makenoidxglossaries` so you need to use `\printnoidxglossary`

This means that when you use `\printglossary` nothing really happens, thus you get only one glossary (the middle command).

Here's your code fixed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\input{acronymes.tex}
\input{glossary.tex}

\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}
\sffamily
 The  typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrshort{gcd}, 

    \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \printnoidxglossary[nonumberlist]
    %\printglossary <-This does nothing



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)