# Very basic glossaries not working on MWE

Tags: glossaries

My MWE is,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited for scientific documents}
}
\begin{document}
should show below, but doesnt. 
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

produces the following PDF document with the text ('should show below, but doesnt. ') but no glossary. The glossary package has been installed/reinstalled. I am using WinEdt11 and PDFTeXify.

Comment: You need to add `\gls{latex}` somewhere in your body text. The glossary will only be printed if there is at least one reference to a glossary entry in the document.

Comment: Maybe also useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110095/277964 with comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110095/list-of-acronyms-is-not-displayed#comment247882_112487

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it is still not working when I cite the glossary entry in the text body:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language especially suited for scientific documents}
}
\begin{document}
\printglossaries
 You should cite the glossary entry: \gls{latex} % Reference the glossary entry
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, when I add the `glossaries-extra` with the `automake` option, you get what you are looking for:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\usepackage[nonumberlist,automake]{glossaries-extra} % nonumberlist avoids numbering the lsit

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language especially suited for scientific documents}
}
\begin{document}
You should cite the glossary entry: \gls{latex} % Reference the glossary entry

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

A little bit more customizable working example is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,symbols]{glossaries}
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language especially suited for scientific documents}
}
\begin{document}
You should cite the glossary entry: \gls{latex} % Reference the glossary entry

\printglossary[style=long,nonumberlist,title={List of abbreviations and acronyms\vspace{-0.3cm}}]
\pagebreak
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need `glossaries-extra`. Package `glossaries` also provides option `automake`. However, you even do not need option `automake`, if you follow the `glossaries` manual and run `makeglossaries` (or `makeindex` with the documented parameters).