# Perl Interpreter could not be found

Tags: latexmk, perl

I downloaded MikTeX and got TeXworks. I try to follow the manual and create an example document. But I get an error message in the "Console output" window: "Latexmk.exe: The Perl intetpreter could not be found."

Is this Perl interpreter something that I have to download separately? I thought everything would be included in the package. I have Windows.

Comment: Only Latexmk should require Perl, does the other compile options work? I.e. pdfLaTeX, or pdfLateX + BibTeX + Makeindex?

Answer (score 6):

install the free one from http://www.perl.org/get.html#win32  then it should work.

Comment: sure, but when you have a bibliography or an index or references in your document, using `latexmk` will make sense.