# Makeglossaries - cannot compile glossary list

Tags: glossaries, texworks, perl

I am trying to get the `glossaries` package to work. I have created a minimal `.tex` file to test it.

I am using TeXworks. My `.tex` file currently looks like this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,amscd}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{test}{
    name=Test,
    description={is a test}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

This is a \gls{test}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The compiled pdf has the sentence "This is a Test", but there is no glossary list. I am currently compiling under the option "pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX".

I have tried compiling just under MakeIndex by itself and then compiling the pdf again, but there is still no list.

I have tried adding a "makeglossaries" option to the list of compiling options according to the following directions I found:

> "You go to TeXWorks > Preferences > Typesetting, and add a processing tool. Name it "makeglossaries" (or whatever you'd like, really), enter the program "makeglossaries" (which should be already installed somewhere---don't worry about the full pathname), and add a single argument: "$basename" so that your main filename will be passed to the makeglossaries process."

But when I compile under the new "makeglossaries" option I get the following error:

> `makeglossaries.exe: The Perl interpreter could not be found.`

After searching for info on this error I downloaded ActivePerl, following the link from this Stack Exchange question: [Perl Interpreter could not be found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113707/perl-interpreter-could-not-be-found). But I still get the error when compiling under the "makeglossaries" option.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the glossary list to appear in the compiled pdf?

Comment: Is `perl.exe` on your operating system's path? To test it, open the [command prompt](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/terminal.html) and run `perl --version`.

Comment: After doing what you said I get message beginning: `This is perl 5, version 16, subversion....`, along with some copyright information.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like perl has been correctly installed, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I don't use Windows, so I can't help further, but perhaps someone else can.

Comment: Good know the install worked. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Do you use MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: @Speravir: MiKTeX

Comment: @cmhughes: Can you be more specific? What is arara and how would I use it to solve this?

Comment: @cmhughes: But only, when it also runs on command line without `arara`.

Comment: @user1985459: BTW A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @user1985459: There is already an older question,that looks like a solution first, but I suspect it does not really help: [How to makeglossaries with TeXworks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13152).

Comment: Does `makeglossaries` run okay from the command prompt? Perhaps you need to specify the full path to `makeglossaries.exe` in [the `MakeGlossaries` preferences](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/build.html#fig:texworks-makeglossaries).