# \printglossary does not produce any content

Tags: glossaries

I am having some trouble using glossaries in LateX (TeXnicCenter) and hope someone could give me some advice.
I am using the package `\usepackage[toc, acronym, section=section]{glossaries}` to get a glossary for acronyms. I definded some acronyms e.g.

```
\newacronym{Bitkom}{Bitkom} {Bundesverband Informationswirtschaft, Telekommunikation und neue Medien e.V.}
```

and if I am using `\gls{Bitkom}` at first it displays the whole text, at second it only displays `Bitkom`.

So everything is alright except the

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,style=long]
```

command, it doesn`t display anything, but I want it to print all used acronyms.

Could someone help me solving this problem please?

```
\usepackage[toc, acronym, section=section]{glossaries}
...
\newacronym{Bitkom}{Bitkom} {Bundesverband Informationswirtschaft, Telekommunikation und neue Medien e.V.}
...
\makeglossaries
...
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis,style=long]
```

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Comment: Did you run `makeglossaries` on your main Tex-file?

Answer (score 2):

After renameing the main.tex file, by deleting all space, the answer in this thread worked for me:
[\printglossaries is not generating anything for me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43759/printglossaries-is-not-generating-anything-for-me)