# why does \printglossary refuse to print anything

Tags: glossaries, texi2dvi

Can someone help me understand what's missing from this simply usages of
the glossaries package?  The document doesn't print any glossary at all.
And the log file complains that test.acr and test.gls are missing.

I've investigated related issue [\printglossary does not produce any content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150196/printglossary-does-not-produce-any-content)
but that does not seem to help.

Normally I'm using texi2dvi to compile my documents.  If I need to run makeglossaries manually (or as part of the makefile) what's the model for using it.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[acronym,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{xyzzy}
{
    name=\ensuremath{\bigcup V},
    description={Unary union operator}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\begin{document}
\gls{xyzzy}
\acrshort{gcd}
\appendix
\chapter{Test chapter}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Custom acronyms title}]

\printglossary[title={Custom glossary title}]


\end{document}
```

Comment: I have discovered that I can run pdflatex, then makeglossaries, then texi2dvi and the glossaries appear.  but this takes VVEERRRRYYYY long to compile.   Is it the best way?

Comment: `texi2dvi` is a quite old script that doesn't know about `glossaries`. What about switching to more modern tools such as `arara` or `latexmk`?

Comment: Should I be using latexmk instead? according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180759/latexmk-vs-texi2dvi  latexmk is much slower than texi2dvi.

Comment: There's a section on `make` at the end of [Incorporating makeglossaries or makeglossaries-lite or bib2gls into the document build](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you modify the old `texi2dvi` script to take care of `makeglossaries`, I don't think you can get away with it.

With the new version of `arara` (version 4), you can simply add something at the top of your document and compile with `arara`:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries if changed('acn') || changed('glo')
% arara: pdflatex if changed('acn') || changed('glo')

\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[acronym,numberedsection]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{xyzzy}
{
    name=\ensuremath{\bigcup V},
    description={Unary union operator}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\begin{document}
\gls{xyzzy}
\acrshort{gcd}
\appendix
\chapter{Test chapter}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Custom acronyms title}]

\printglossary[title={Custom glossary title}]


\end{document}
```

Running `arara` the first time will show

```
> arara jim
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing 'jim.tex' (size: 585 bytes, last modified: 07/12/2018
12:22:13), please wait.

(PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS
(MakeGlossaries) The MakeGlossaries software ............ SUCCESS
(PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS

Total: 1.52 seconds
```

The second time we get

```
> arara jim
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing 'jim.tex' (size: 585 bytes, last modified: 07/12/2018
12:22:13), please wait.

(PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS

Total: 0.79 seconds
```

which shows that the unnecessary runs of `makeglossaries` and `pdflatex` are not performed.

Alternatively, use `latexmk`: add a file named `latexmkrc` to the working directory containing

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}
```

(courtesy of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44316/4427)

and run `latexmk -pdf jim` instead of `texi2dvi -p jim` (use the appropriate file name, of course).