# Highlighting First Occurence of Word. Making it Case Insensitive

Tags: highlighting

first time asking a question.

I'm implementing egregs answer from this question: [Highlight First Occurrence of a Particular Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50566/highlight-first-occurrence-of-a-particular-word/50574#50574?newreg=8ac4f350012146388a56dc6c837bea0c)

```
%%% Code to set up special term treatment
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialterms}[1]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do
  {\@namedef{specialterm@\detokenize\expandafter{\next}}{}}%
}
\newcommand\term[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{specialterm@\detokenize{#1}}
    {#1}{\emph{#1}\global\expandafter\let\csnamespecialterm@\detokenize{#1}\endcsna    me\relax}%
}
\makeatother

%%% Here we define the special terms we want
\specialterms{foo,bar,baz}
```

This emphasises the first mention of the words in the `\specialterms` list. This is working fine at the moment. I want it to recognise capitalised versions of the words listed in `\specialterms`, so that it works better with the first word in a sentence. Using the example over, I want `\term{Foo}` to be emphasised without having to add Foo to the `\specialterms` list.

I tried the following:

```
\@ifundefined{specialterm@\MakeLowercase{\detokenize{#1}}}
```

This does not work however. I think I need to add some `\csnames` and `\expandafter` commands and what have you, but my understanding of what these commands actually do is very limited. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. I should maybe have posted this as a comment in the original thread, but as I just joined the site I don't have enough reputation to do this.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Regarding your question, have you had a look at mforbes' answer to the same question?  It uses the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package and it does support capitalisation of terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can examine the lowercased version of the term.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% Code to set up special term treatment
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialterms}[1]{%
  \@for\next:=#1\do
    {\@namedef{specialterm@\detokenize\expandafter{\next}}{}}%
}
\newcommand\term[1]{%
  \specialterm@lower{#1}% save the lowercased term in \specialterm@current
  \@ifundefined{specialterm@\specialterm@current}
    {#1}% not the first occurrence
    {% first occurrence
     \emph{#1}% print it in italics
     % then undefine the macro
     \global\expandafter\let\csname specialterm@\specialterm@current\endcsname\relax
    }%
}
\newcommand{\specialterm@lower}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\next{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\lowercase{\def\noexpand\specialterm@current{\next}}}\x
}
\makeatother

%%% Here we define the special terms we want
\specialterms{foo,bar,baz}

\begin{document}

First occurrence of \term{foo} and second occurrence of \term{foo}.

First occurrence of \term{baz}. \term{Bar} and
again \term{bar} and \term{baz} and \term{foo}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler implementation with `expl3`, which also works with UTF-8 (not required, though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

%%% Code to set up special term treatment
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\specialterms}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \bool_new:c { \__lasse_boolean_name:n { ##1 } _bool }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\term}{m}
 {
  \bool_if:cTF { \__lasse_boolean_name:n { #1 } _bool }
   {
    #1
   }
   {
    \emph { #1 }
    \bool_gset_true:c { \__lasse_boolean_name:n { #1 } _bool }
   }
 }

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Nn \__lasse_boolean_name:n
 {
  g_lasse_specialterms_ \str_lowercase:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% Here we define the special terms we want
\specialterms{foo,bar,báz,bäz}

\begin{document}

First occurrence of \term{foo} and second occurrence of \term{foo}.

First occurrence of \term{báz}. \term{Bar} and
again \term{bar} and \term{báz} and \term{foo}.

\term{Bäz} \term{bäz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\term}[1]{%
\lowercase{\expandafter\ifx\csname mt\detokenize{#1}term\endcsname\relax}
\emph{#1}%
\lowercase{\expandafter\let\csname mt\detokenize{#1}term\endcsname\empty}%
\else#1\fi}
\begin{document}
First occurrence of \term{foo} and second occurrence of \term{foo}.

First occurrence of \term{baz}. Now \term{bar} and
again \term{bar} and \term{baz} and \term{foo}. \term{fOo}


First occurrence of \term{BOM}. Now \term{bOm} and
again \term{BOm} and \term{bom} and \term{FOo} and \term{fOo}.
\end{document}
```