# Can my custom dependency for latexmk be improved?

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

In my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226) on how to make [`latexmk`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf)  use [`makeglossaries`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) for generating glossaries, I propose the following custom dependency:

```perl
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}
```

When `latexmk` is run on the LaTeX input file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{test}{name={Test}, description={A Test}}

\newacronym{AT}{AT}{A Test}

\makeglossaries

\glsaddall

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

the *first time* it invokes `latex`, `makeglossaries` and `latex` (in that order). This is as expected, since `makeglossaries` processes all defined glossaries (here the main glossary and the list of acronyms) in a single call.

Now, assume I apply some trivial changes to *both* the term `test` and the acronym `AT` (e.g., I convert `Test` to lowercase). Then, the command sequence issued by `latexmk` is `latex`, `makeglossaries`, `makeglossaries` and `latex`. Thus, `makeglossaries` is called twice while it would suffice to call it once.

Hence, I wonder: Is it possible to improve my custom dependency such that `latexmk` also handles the preceding case correctly?

Comment: So I am not sure about this, but as it is Perl, chances are, that a regular expression could work. The idea would be to have one line (maybe seen as one dependency) matching both files at the same time. This would result in something like `'(glo)|(acn)'` or `'(gls)|(acr)'`. This is completely untested, but if it does not work, it should be simple for a Perlian to extend `latexmk` according to that idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two runs of `makeglossaries` are because of an inadequacy in `latexmk`. The problem is that a custom dependency is considered to have a single input file and a single output file.  But `makeglossaries` has an input file and an output file for each glossary; in the example given, the input files have extensions `acn` and `glo`, and the output files have extensions `acr` and `gls`.

It would require significant rewriting of `latexmk` to improve this situation. I suspect the extra running time from the extra runs of `makeglossaries` is normally fairly low compared with the running of `latex` itself, so this isn't a high priority for me to fix this.

Alternatively, you could rewrite the definitions of the custom dependencies to directly run `makeindex` instead of delegating that to `makeglossaries`.

What happens is that `latexmk` creates two custom dependencies, as expected: for `acn` to `acr`, and for `glo` to `gls`.  When a change is made to both glossaries, `latexmk` sees that both rules have become out-of-date and runs `makeglossaries`. So the two runs are expected.

But this leaves a puzzle of why is there only one run of `makeglossaries` the first time the source file is processed by `latexmk`. This is because from a virgin set up, `latexmk` first runs `makeglossaries` to create the `gls` file.  As a side effect this also creates the `acr` file. Now on an initial run, `latexmk` sees that the `acr` file is newer than the `acn` file, so it doesn't bother to make it.  But on subsequent runs, `latexmk` uses a criterion of change of file contents rather than relative file times between input and output files to determine whether to remake output files.  Hence the first time through, only one run of `makeglossaries` is done.

**Added note:**
I mentioned that the custom dependencies can written differently to call `makeindex` directly rather than delegating that to `makeglossaries`.  This optimizes the number of runs.  Here's one way of doing it:

```perl
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeindex');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeindex');
sub run_makeindex {
   my $source = $$Psource;
   my $dest = $$Pdest;
   my $log = $dest."LOG";
   my $cmd = "makeindex %O -s \"$_[0].ist\"  -t \"$log\" -o \"$dest\" \"$source\"";
   if ($silent) { $cmd =~ s/%O/-q/; }
   else { $cmd =~ s/%O//; }
   return system $cmd;
}
```

To make the code simpler and the same for the two cases, I've uses a couple of internal variables of `latexmk` that specify the source and destination files for the dependency.  I've set the names of the log files for `makeindex` to something easier to create than those of `makeglossaries`.

Comment: OK, this means that it’s not impossible to improve things: The `run_makeglossaries` subroutine or, even better, the `makeglossaries` program itself could check timestamps …

Comment: @JohnCollins: If you add `<!-- language: lang-perl -->` before a code block (or `<!-- language-all: lang-perl -->` if there are several), they'll get the correct syntax highlighting.

Comment: @JohnCollins: Thanks! The thing is that I normally use `xindy` instead of `makeindex` for sorting. Relying on `makeglossaries` is a big advantage in this case since the correct language and input encoding are automatically passed to `xindy`.