# pdflatexmk doesn't run makeglossaries for glossaries package (TeXShop, OSX)

Tags: glossaries, texshop, latexmk

I'm trying to get the following document to work with a single run of pdflatexmk:
(I've included my entire preamble to be sure)

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-ibid,
sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib=true,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=100,
url=false, 
doi=true,
eprint=false,
hyperref=true
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage[xindy,toc,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=50mm, right=15mm, bottom=20mm,
headsep=12.7mm, footskip=12.7mm}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{} 
\fancyhead[C]{} 
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} 
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\newpage
\newacronym{gi}{GI}{The General Inquirer}
bla bla bla \gls{gi} bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

The entire console-output for the pdflatexmk run can be found here since it's quite lenghty:
http://pastebin.com/y1aKpt8c

Comment: Welcome to the site! When it comes to cross-platform, cross-editor automation, the `arara` tool trumps all :) Have you looked at it?

Comment: Perhaps the following questions can help: [How to make Latexmk use makeglossaries?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1226) and [Can my custom dependency for latexmk be improved?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60204).

Comment: The solutions from that question do not seem to have any effect for me (I went with the latexmkrc file in my working directory). I'll look into arera today.

Comment: ..looked at arara and it works great:    % arara: pdflatex
    % arara: biber
    % arara: makeglossaries
    % arara: pdflatex
    % arara: pdflatex

Comment: @Matthias The solution in one of the answers (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44316/8495) to an earlier question does work; I've just tried it on your file.  The checked answer in that question won't work for you because it doesn't define the dependency for acronyms, which you need.

Comment: @Matthias While the `arara` solution works, note that it will run `pdflatex` exactly three times whether not that is needed.  For recompilations after small changes, fewer runs are normally needed, and on some documents more runs are needed.  `Latexmk` is optimal (or close to it) on the number of runs, which is important for large documents.

Comment: @Matthias which OS are you compiling on? (Getting Latexmk to work on Windows is slightly more troublesome than on Unix-derivates).