# Can't get symbol list to work

Tags: glossaries

I am using an finished template at my school for writing my thesis in LaTeX. I am using TeXShop. My problem is that I can't get the symbol list to appear. It is no problem to get my abbreviations to appear. In the abbreviations I am using e.g.

```
\newacronym{ARMA}{ARMA}{auto regressive moving average}
```

For my symbol list I am using e.g

```
\newglossaryentry{symb:N}{sort={3},
name={$\mathbb N$},
first={first $\mathbb N$},
text={additional $\mathbb N$},
description={Set of natural numbers},
type=symbolslist}
```

In my main file I am typing:

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long ,title=Abbreviations, toctitle=Abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=long ,title=Symbols]
```

Settings:

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\include{Abbr} % all abbreviations
\include{Symbols} % all symbols
```

I am compiling it with: latex – pdflatexmk – latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You need to run `makeglossaries` as well as `pdflatex` to make the lists appear. I'm a little confused by your compilation list. Why are you using both `latex` and `pdflatexmk`? By the way, use `\input` instead of `\include` to input the files containing the definitions, see [Why shouldn't I use \include to include my glossary definitions?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#include).

Comment: Thanks for reply! But I don't have any "make glossaries" in my "compiling list"? There are for example Bibtex, Latex, PdflatexMK and so on, should makeglossaries also be there?

Comment: You can get `pdflatexmk` to do this for you. Have a look at [How to make Latexmk use makeglossaries?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries)

Comment: There may be a `makeglossaries` engine in TeXShop's directory in your home Library directory e.g. under `/Users/YourUserName/Library/TeXShop/engines/disabled`. Note that that path will not be quite correct as I have not used a Mac for a while and can't remember the details. `disabled`, for example, might be `inactive` or similar. There are instructions there for activating the engines. Or you can read TeXShop's help.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, did got it working now! 
Though it some times complain when I am using a \gls command in a equation, do you know something about that?
E.g.
\begin{equation}
(1-\sum_{j=1}^{p} \phi_j B^j \gls{symb:backshift})(1-B)^d(D_t-\mu)=(1-\sum_{j=1}^{q} \theta_j B^j)
\end{equation}

Comment: You'll need to create a new question for that with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the principal issue could be settled by comments (especially N. Talbot's explanations about makeglossaries

Comment: @ChristianHupfer If it can be settled at all, it should be settled in an answer. Voting to keep open.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Well, Nicola should answer it then. I usually don't take over comments by other users and squeeze an answer out of it. (Although I would have suggested the same procedure, however)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, please consider writing an answer :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred It seems from the comments that this is just a dup of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries Perhaps closing it as a duplicate would be more appropriate.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Agreed. Voting to close :-)