# Which packages require command-line steps (not e.g. pdflatex) to compile?

Tags: glossaries, indexing, auxiliary-files

Are there any packages which depend on other 'non-standard' command line programs (i.e. not `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and friends)?

When writing a document in e.g. `LaTeX`, this of course needs to be compiled with e.g. `pdflatex`. With a bibliography, this requires a separate call to `bibtex` (or `biber`), another command-line program.

I have found that `makeglossaries` and `makeindex` are two such commands (used by the packages [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/) and [makeidx](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeidx), respectively). Are there any more which are in common use, perhaps with their own associated auxillary files?

I'm asking as I'm trying to automate the compiling process a little for common-use cases. While `[latexmk](http://ctan.mackichan.com/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf)' is great, it doesn't appear to support glossaries at this time.

Updated - sorry `latexmk` can be tweaked to include `makeglossaries` as below, afraid I didn't know about this.

Updated - there are indeed a *lot* of these 'supporting' commands. @Nicola Talbot's comment gives the longest list (http://ctan.org/tex-archive/support) - again, new to me and will be glad to accept as an answer.
Agreed that `makeindex` is now standard; by 'common-use' I guess it's my own use case. [ChkTeX](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/support/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf) looks like integrating into the workflow. [try](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/support/try/try-doc.pdf) also looks like a good approach to integrating these command-line steps.

Comment: latexmk *does* support glossaries; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries

Comment: `makeglossaries` invokes either `makeindex` or `xindy`, according to requirements, but I wouldn't call `makeindex` any more "non-standard" than `bibtex` as both have been available with TeX distributions for a long time.

Comment: There will be lots. What do you count as 'common-use'? `graphicx`/`graphics`/`standalone`/`tikz`/etc. can use `convert` (and similar). `tikz`/`pgf`/`pgfplots` can use `gnuplot`. `python`, `sage`, `asymptote`. I guess that `metapost` must surely count as standard but what about the auxiliary wrappers for conversion to PDF? Also, there are variants of `bibtex` such as `bibtex8`.

Comment: There are several sub-directories on CTAN that list applications, such as [tex-archive/indexing](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing), [tex-archive/biblio](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio) and [tex-archive/support](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/support)

Comment: `pythontex` comes to mind.

Comment: ...and [`biber`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biber).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer.) There are a number of sub-directories on CTAN that list supporting applications. The main one is [tex-archive/support](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/support), but there are also some subject specific sub-directories, such as [tex-archive/indexing](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/indexing) (indexing applications) and [tex-archive/biblio](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio) (bibliographic applications). The [tex-archive/graphics](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics) directory has a mixture of packages and applications.

I think the oldest supporting applications that are widely in use are probably [`makeindex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makeindex), which was created by Pehong Chen in 1987, and [`bibtex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtex), which was created by Oren Patashnik and Leslie Lamport in 1985. The 1985 version of "LaTeX: A Document Preparation System" mentions `bibtex`. It doesn't mention `makeindex` but does document the commands `\makeindex`, `index`, `\makeglossaries` and `\glossaries` that are used to create external files that can be post-processed by LaTeX.