# Why won't latexmk create a glossary using makeindex under the memoir class?

Tags: memoir, latexmk, makeindex

I'm using latexmk to create my LaTeX documents, calling it from Aquamacs. My LatexMk file (also known as a latexmkrc file) contains the only following:

```
$do_cd = '0';
$quote_filenames = '0';
$makeindex = 'makeindex -s basic.gst -o glossary.gls glossary.glo';
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S';
$pdf_previewer = 'open -a skim';
$view = 'pdf';
```

Everything works as desired, except that no glossary.gls file is created on a latexmk run. Nor, therefore, is an index added to the document. A MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,book,dutch]{memoir}
\makeglossary[glossary]
\begin{document}
\glossary[glossary]{test}{test}
\printglossary[glossary]
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, the title here is incorrect, this is not an index, but a glossary. Secondly nothing to do with the `memoir` class. Latexmk never fires any `makeindex` instructions, probably since no `.idx` file is detected. You probably need a custom dependency to make latexmk react to glossary files.

Comment: First hit on google: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1228/3929

Comment: Spot on regarding the title and the suggested solution @daleif. I do however think that the memoir class was relevant to my problem, because the glossary functionality is provided by it.

Comment: I think you'll get the same issues with the glossary package. The good thing about that package is that it uses a separate script so you can have both a glossary and an index. The manner you were doing it excluded the index possibility via latexmk