# Glossary does not print in Visual Studio Code, but does print on Overleaf.com

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, latexmk

I am trying to get my glossary to print in Visual Studio Code,
the same files do print a glossary on Overleaf.com.

MWE on Overleaf.com: https://www.overleaf.com/read/kztypntcdrvy

Visual Studio Code / latexmk stated that the files: main.acr and main.gls were missing.
However I do have the files: main.acn and main.glo.

I am using, Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 1 January 2015, version: 4.41.

Comment: Does `latexmk` know it needs to run `makeglossaries`? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries for some pointers.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for your reply, it works now. I had to run `makeglossaries main`
`latexmk -pdf main.tex`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution from @Marijn**

I had to run `makeglossaries main` and `latexmk -pdf main.tex`

Comment: you might want to update, I think modern versions of `latexmk` might be able to detect the need for `makeglossaries` automatically.