# Luatex os.execute not working

Tags: pdf, tex-core, luatex

1. I've hooked luatex's `stop_run` callback so I can do some processing on the output pdf after it is generated.
2. To process the pdf I need to call os.execute. When doing so I an error saying "All command executes disabled" but otherwise everything works normal execute os.execute doesn't execute the command I want.
3. I use `-shell-escape` to try and get os.execute to work
4. I then get an error that that the

   Failed to open PDF file: 
     Main.pdf
   Errors encountered.  No output created.
   Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
   Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
     Main.pdf
   Errors encountered.  No output created.
   Done.  Input errors, so no output created.

yet Main.pdf is clearly created but os.execute still does not execute(note that adding `-shell-execute` to the command line is the only change that creates this error). I get a different error from my os.execute too. It is no `1` instead.

ALSO! If I simply use 'copy ...' to try and copy the main.pdf file to a tmp location(thinking maybe it was locked) I get a new pdf but it is not complete as if the buffers were not fully flushed. (if that were the case then I would just get that annoying error message but otherwise everything else would be ok)

To recap:

1. Trying to get os.excute to work. I use `shell-escape` but this cases other problems
2. My callback is suppose to be called after the pdf is generated BUT when I simply try to copy it, it seems to not copy all of the file. Either the pdf is not being flushed or something is adding additional stuff to the end of the pdf(although I wouldn't expect this and at the very least would expect the original pdf to be valid).

I've tried writing several minutes and the copy still doesn't get the whole file(it's missing about 1kb at the end after some hyperref stuff).

Anyone have any ideas whats going on?

(if I can get this to work I should have the ability to make `\include` precompilable(so it will not compile the included file unless the tex file changed but will import a precompiled version))

Answer (score 8):

You need to write a wrapper script around your LuaTeX run. The `stop_run` callback is run before the PDF file is closed / finished, no way to have a correct PDF file at that point (or at any other point, except for *after* the LuaTeX run.

Comment: For the curious: See the file  https://github.com/pgundlach/LuaTeX/blob/master/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/pdf/pdfgen.w#L2562

Comment: There might be a different callback for that purpose in a future version of LuaTeX.

Comment: It would be very nice to have a call back after the pdf is written ;/ I thought `finish_pdffile` was it but it's actually before `stop_run`.  It would not be hard to add a callback to be called after the pdf. I guess all the work I've put into making a precompiled version of `include` is worthless now ;/ (well, less I do it in batch or make file which I don't really want to do)

Comment: @Uiy See the discussion following http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2012-May/003647.html

Comment: Patrick, is the source code you linked fairly recent? Also, I guess you are part of the development of lualatex? What kind of timeframe would one expect for such changes to take place?

Comment: @Uiy I not part of any LuaTex team. The source code is pretty much up to date and I'd expect it to be in texlive 2013.

Comment: `            } else if (callback_id > 0) {
                res = run_callback(callback_id, "->");
            }
        }
        libpdffinish(pdf);
        if (pdf->draftmode == 0)
            close_file(pdf->file);` 
...
00452 void libpdffinish(void)
00453 {
00454     xfree(fb_array);
00455     xfree(char_array);
00456     xfree(job_id_string);
00457     fm_free();
00458     t1_free();
00459     enc_free();
00460     img_free();
00461     vf_free();
00462     epdf_free();
00463     ttf_free();
00464     sfd_free();
00465     glyph_unicode_free();
00466     zip_free();
00467 }

Comment: It seems that the only thing that happens after the callback is freeing objects and closing the file. Doesn't seem like there is any reason `stop_run` to be before close.file and a flush should definitely take care of the issue.

Comment: @Uiy This is not the appropriate place to discuss that issue. Let's move on to the mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

LuaTeX has a callback that can be used for this.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

123

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function()
    -- do something with the output PDF here, for example:
    -- io.open(tex.jobname..".pdf", "rb"):read("a")
    -- the line above reads the complete content of the PDF
    -- or os.execute(...)
end, "final callback to rename pdf file")
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the documentation (texdoc luatex) states...

> Use it at your own risk.

So, if you use this solution be prepared to debug any issue that might happen later in new compiler versions.

---

Looking around, there's an alternative, although it's more ugly.

I notice that the `standalone` package can execute some shell command to convert the resulting PDF to another file format. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51766/250119

Reading its source code, it roughly does the following (assuming main file name is `a.tex`):

```python
if (flag convert is given) and not (internal run):
    shell escape run("latex 'internal run = true; input{a.tex}'")
    shell escape run("pdf2svg a.pdf a.svg")
    stop program
```

As such, when the compilation of the main file starts, it spawns another LaTeX process to **actually** compile the file,
then in the parent LaTeX process it does the shell escape to convert, and stop the main process.

Comment: Similar question: [compiling - Can TeX post-process the PDF it produces? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21310/can-tex-post-process-the-pdf-it-produces/705583#705583)