# Flush latex file io buffers

Tags: tex-core, luatex

Is there any way to flush latex's file io buffers. Because of something I'm trying to achieve I have to copy/modify the outputted pdf after it is created(but in the same compile run). The problem is, it seems, that the pdf is not fully flushed before I copy/modify it. The result is a partially copied file which end up corrupt.

Is there any way to get tex/latex/lutex/lualatex to flush the buffers before I do the copy? (the copy is in lualatex and happens right after the pdf is generated. It is not done separately)

Comment: Do you mean the main output (`.dvi` or `.pdf`, depending on mode)? If so, the answer is 'no' as closing the output is the last job TeX does. On the other hand, if you mean the streams we can write to from within TeX then it is doable.

Comment: Shouldn't we close this question now that you have asked the more specific one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55743/luatex-os-execute-not-working

Comment: @PatrickGundlach I added this because it is pretty specific and people have gotten on to me in the past about writing multiple questions per post. This one is actually more specific to the problem.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to do that. Future versions of LuaTeX might handle that.

Answer (score 6):

One TeX run is intimately linked to the generation of one output file, either `.dvi` or `.pdf`. As such, the output file is only closed right at the end of the run (there is no value in the run continuing once the file is written). With pdfTeX and XeTeX this is not going to alter, although it is possible that LuaTeX may have altered behaviour. As such, it is normal to carry out more complex operations using a wrapper around several TeX runs. This could of course be done using the Lua part of LuaTeX (see for example how ConTeXt Mk IV works).