# Command to flush log file

Tags: filesystem-access, logging

For the `tikzDevice`, I want to communicate with a LaTeX process by sending input (generated LaTeX code) to its `stdin` and parsing output that is written using `\immediate\write`. In some cases I need also to look at the log file, but I have noticed that it seems to be buffered: When I start `pdflatex` at the console and type a document, the log file `texput.log` doesn't seem to be written until I end the document.

Is there a way to flush the buffers for the log file, so that everything accumulated so far is written?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @egreg: That's too bad. Can I at least read the log file from within LaTeX, and perhaps copy it to somewhere else? Or perhaps close/reopen the log file? I know I can `\typeout` to overflow the buffer so that it's emptied eventually, but that's not exactly elegant...

Comment: It depends on what you want to read in the log file. Closing and reopening it is out of the question, I'm afraid; and it's not available from within TeX.

Comment: @egreg: I need to detect missing characters from fonts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165665/8057. Currently, this is done by looking a the log file.

Comment: Do you know about `\iffontchar`?

Comment: @egreg: No, I didn't; but the input can be arbitrary LaTeX code...

Comment: Remark from future: it's possible to write to a file named e.g. `|cat` so that TeX will spawn a new process and every line written to that "file" will be written to the stdin of that process instead (without buffering). Note that the command name must include a period otherwise `.tex` will be appended. I use this technique for my pythonimmediate package...

Comment: Related question [tex core - Flush latex file io buffers - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55751/flush-latex-file-io-buffers)