# copy finalised PDF to new directory

Tags: shell-escape

I want to automatically make a copy of the finalised PDF in a new directory once it is compiled.

As part of my workflow, each article (of my thesis) (and the associated graphics) is stored in its own directory. I then import each file into a master file as a combined thesis.

I already do this with the tex file itself (make a daily backup).

I have the following code at the start of each article tex file (which basically copies the existing tex file to a backup directory and renames it with today's date so I have a history of tex files):

```
\immediate\write18{mkdir \currfiledir backup}
\immediate\write18{cp '\currfiledir \currfilename' '\currfiledir backup/\currfilebase\string_\the\year-\the\month-\the\day .\currfileext'}
```

I want to have similar code that copies the finalised PDF file from the master directory into the directory of each article. Something like this (but this didn't work).

```
\immediate\write18{cp \jobname.pdf  \currfiledir\currfilebase.pdf}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you have a saved copy of the tex file you can easily recreate the PDF file -- you could o this manually or you could use `\write18` to run pdflatex directly after you execute the lines above. Alternatively, you could use `\write18` to copy the PDF file in addition to the tex file.

This said, I think you would be much better off using a *version control program* to do this properly. I highly recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/). There is a bit of a learning curve but it will keep track of your daily snap shots without you having to keep all these old files lying around.

Comment: pdflatex (and other web2c engines) have an commandline flag `-output-directory=DIR   use existing DIR as the directory to write files in`

Comment: making the backup copy when you run tex seems strange, don't you want to make it when you edit the file (ie your editor should do it?

Comment: You can't use `\write18` to move the PDF file, because the PDF file is finalized when executing `\end`, which comes later than any `\write` in the input.

Comment: Andrew's comment deserves more than the +1 I can provide: you have a Unix-like system, which means you have access to `make` and your choice of scripting languages and version control systems. This is what they're designed for. Will make a quick example of how this could be accomplished.

Comment: @Andrew - I'm using multiple computers to access my Dropbox stored files. Would `git` work in this case?

Comment: You can use symlinks (see command `ln -s`) for this.

Comment: Yes git works across multiple machines/accounts. It was written to manage code written by multiple developers so one of its main requirements is that it needs to work across many different computers. I use git for all of my papers these days and sync them remotely with bitbucket and different copmuters.

Comment: You can use git/github for version control instead of creating backup of each folders.

Answer (score 4):

Related (at least in my opinion): [How to properly 'make' a latex project?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40738) and [Using makefile to create tar archive](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?p=153826&sid=4fe48b63415fb8ef052e19876292ac5c#p153826)

Basically, I'd make a Makefile, use `latexmk` to handle document builds, and `tar` to make regular backups (any version control system is better than `tar`, but there's practically no learning curve to this one).

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: MyDoc.pdf all clean

all: MyDoc.pdf

MyDoc.pdf: MyDoc.tex
        latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interactive=nonstopmode" -use-make MyDoc.tex

clean:
        latexmk -CA

backup:
        tar -czf ../MyDocs-`date +%Y.%m.%d`.tar.gz .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I currently don't explicitly use a make file, but I do use `latemk`. I'm not so interested in more than a daily backup (and I'm not productive enough to think I would be losing that much...), that's why I'm making backups with `write18`. I'll try out your approach though. Ideally, though, I would like not to have too complicated an approach. A single line in my tex file would be preferable.

Comment: If you're going to the command line to run `latexmk`, then running `make` for compilation isn't any harder. If your editor is automatically running `latexmk`, then there may be a way to have it run `make` instead. Embedding shell commands (3, so far) into the document runs against my inclinations, and I think it'd get tedious if you ever add more commands.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this question is a special case of [Can TeX post-process the PDF it produces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21310/250119)

Solution adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648388/250119 , use `wrapup_run` hook. LuaLaTeX only.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

123

\begin{luacode*}
luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function()
    local output_file=token.get_macro("currfiledir")..token.get_macro("currfilebase")..".pdf"
    print("======== Copying finalized PDF to "..output_file)
    local outfile=io.open(output_file, "wb")
    outfile:write(io.open(tex.jobname..".pdf", "rb"):read("a"))
    outfile:close()
end, "final callback to copy pdf file")
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex -recorder path/to/file.tex`.