# Compile to PDF file with different name than the source

Tags: macros, pdf

I have a latex document containing some problems and their solutions. I also have a macro `\excludecomment{sol}` which if uncommented, excludes the solution environments. (Similar command is there for `prob` environment.)

The general question is whether I can include a command in these macros or otherwise so that depending on whether the macro is active or not is reflected in the filename of the PDF file (e.g., by adding a _sol to the filename when the solutions are present.)

Comment: Changing the jobname from within the document is tricky. However it would be possible to automatically create both the versions of your document and name them accordingly, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files/5265#5265

Comment: Related: [jobname - How to influence the name of the pdf file created with pdfLaTeX (from within the source code)? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19182/how-to-influence-the-name-of-the-pdf-file-created-with-pdflatex-from-within-the/666901#666901)

Answer (score 6):

You can't change the name of the output files/the name of the .pdf file *during* the TeX run/LaTeX run.

The reason is:

The output files are created anew and opened for writing right at the beginning of the TeX run/LaTeX run.
(E.g., the .log file is created anew and opened for writing right after starting the tex-executable or latex-executable. E.g., the .pdf file is created anew and opened for writing when shipping out the very first page of the document.  )
The output files (and thus also the .pdf file) are left open for writing until the end of the TeX run/LaTeX run.
With most computer platforms you can't change the name of a file while that file is open for writing.

But with most TeX-platforms you can run tex-binaries/executables with command line options.

One of these options is the option `-jobname`.

If you have the main .tex-file `foo.tex` and compile it by running latex from the command line as

`pdflatex --jobname=bar foo.tex`

, you won't get the output files `foo.aux`, `foo.log` and `foo.pdf`, etc,  but you will get output files `bar.aux`, `bar.log` and `bar.pdf`, etc.

Also the primitive `\jobname` won't deliver the phrase `foo` in this case but will deliver the phrase `bar`.

You can't use a macro for changing the names of output files during the LaTeX run but you can go the other direction:

Create a macro which examines whether the expansion of `\jobname` contains some specific phrase and forks accordingly. Be aware that `\jobname` spits out explicit space tokens of category code 10(space) and explicit character tokens of category code 12(other).

---

Example:

Save the following example as `test.tex` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begingroup    
\makeatletter
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether expansion of \jobname contains no phase "_sol"
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname{<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                                 \jobname contains no phrase "_sol">}%
%%                               {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                                 \jobname contains the phrsae "_sol">}%
\def\UD@GobbleToSol{_sol}%
\@onelevel@sanitize\UD@GobbleToSol
\edef\CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname{%
  \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \noexpand\expandafter{\noexpand\UD@GobbleToSol\jobname\UD@GobbleToSol}%
}%
\expandafter\long\expandafter\def
\expandafter\UD@GobbleToSol\expandafter#\expandafter1\UD@GobbleToSol{}%
\CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname[2]{#1}%
}{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname[2]{#2}%
}%
%% \makeatother not needed. Instead the group is closed.
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname{%
  \excludecomment{sol}%
}{%
  \includecomment{sol}%
}%

\begin{document}

Expansion of \verb|\jobname| is: \texttt{\jobname}

\texttt{\string\jobname} does
\CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname{%
  not%
}{%
  indeed%
}
contain the phrase \verb|_sol|.

Thus solutions
\CheckWhetherNoSolInJobname{%
  are not included%
}{%
  get included also%
}.

\bigskip

This is the question.
\begin{sol}

This is the answer.
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

Compiling from the command line via `pdflatex test.tex` yields `test.pdf` which looks like this:

[image]

Compiling from the command line via `pdflatex --jobname=test_sol test.tex` yields `test_sol.pdf` which looks like this:

[image]

---

---

Another approach could be:

File `test_sol.tex`:

```
\newcommand\solutioninorexclude{%
  \includecomment{sol}%
}%
\input test.tex
```

File `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\providecommand\solutioninorexclude{%
  \excludecomment{sol}%
}%
\solutioninorexclude    

\begin{document}

This is the question.
\begin{sol}

This is the answer.
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

Compiling `test_sol.tex` yields `test_sol.pdf`:

[image]

Compiling `test.tex` yields `test.pdf`:

[image]

A variation on this approach can be having `test.tex` create the file `test_sol.tex` for you automatically in case it does not exist:

When you save the example below as `test.tex` and compile it, you will get a file `test.pdf` which contains the text without solutions. You also get a file `test_sol.tex`. If you compile that, it will—via `\input`—import `test.tex` in a way where `sol`-environments are included. Thus you get a file `test_sol.pdf` which does also contain solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\providecommand\solutioninorexclude{%
  \excludecomment{sol}%
  \includecomment{solinputfile}%
}%
\solutioninorexclude    

\begin{solinputfile}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{\jobname\string_sol.tex}{%
  \@latex@warning@no@line{File \jobname\string_sol.tex already exists. Not generating it}%
}{%
  \@latex@warning@no@line{Generating file \jobname\string_sol.tex}%
  \newwrite\solinputfile
  \immediate\openout\solinputfile\jobname\string_sol.tex\relax
  \immediate\write\solinputfile{%
    \string\newcommand\string\solutioninorexclude{\@percentchar^^J%
    \space\space\string\includecomment{sol}\@percentchar^^J%
    \space\space\string\excludecomment{solinputfile}\@percentchar^^J%
    }\@percentchar^^J%
    \string\input\space\jobname.tex%
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\solinputfile
}%
\endgroup
\end{solinputfile}

\begin{document}

This is the question.
\begin{sol}

This is the answer.
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

---

---

Yet another approach could be using something like the [docstrip](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) package.
The purpose of the [docstrip](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) package is copying files of tex-source-code with having comments removed. It provides means for conditional inclusion of code into the copies.

E.g. if you save the following example as `test.tex` and compile it, you don't get a .pdf file but you get two new text files.

```
%<*ignore>
\input docstrip
\nopreamble
\nopostamble
\askforoverwritetrue
\generate{\file{\jobname\string_sol.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{sol}}}
\generate{\file{\jobname\string_nosol.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{}}}
% Here you can do some \immediate\write18-calls for calling LaTeX or
% TeXify or latexmk for compiling \jobname_sol.tex and
%\jobname_nosol.tex.
% You need to have the \write18-feature enabled for this.
% Some people take enabling \write18 for a security issue.
\csname stop\endcsname
\bye
%</ignore>
\documentclass{article}
% This comment won't occur in the generated files.
% This comment won't occur in the generated files.
\begin{document}
This is the question.
%<*sol>
    
This is the answer.
%</sol>
\end{document}
```

One of these text files is named `test_nosol.tex` and its content is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the question.
\end{document}
```

The other of these text files is named `test_sol.tex` and its content is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the question.

This is the answer.
\end{document}
```

Comment: -jobname is TeX option, no LaTeX option.

Comment: If I do `ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tex bobo` then I can do `bobo --help` or `bobo --jobname=foo bar.tex`. Everything works (the second example only if `bobo.fmt` format is present). But there is no bobo-binary, only TeX binary. The "latex binary" is equivalent with "bobo binary" in this example.

Comment: OK, you are right. Nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same situation **for years** and I just came with the following solution today after browsing TeX.stackexchange. It does not strictly answer your question but I find it easy to use as a workaround solution. I use the `exam` package but this should work for any package where you have the option to comment out some portions using a macro. For the `exam` package, the code that is optionnally included is in the `solution` environment. I created three files with the following scheme (but shorter names in practice):

1) main_questions_only.tex whose entire content is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\noprintanswers
\input{main.tex}
```

2) main_questions_with_solutions.tex whose entire content is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
\input{main.tex}
```

3) main.tex contains everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this question is a special case of [Can TeX post-process the PDF it produces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21310/250119) .

LuaTeX has a callback that can be used for this.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

123

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function()
    local outfile=io.open(tex.jobname.."_sol.pdf", "wb")
    outfile:write(io.open(tex.jobname..".pdf", "rb"):read("a"))
    outfile:close()
    os.remove(tex.jobname..".pdf")
end, "final callback to rename pdf file")
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the documentation (texdoc luatex) states...

> Use it at your own risk.

So, if you use this solution be prepared to debug any issue that might happen later in new compiler versions.

Comment: Also, no shell-escape needed.

Comment: It remains the readers' exercise to figure out how to only do that operation when some "flag" is set. Also, the in-file is not closed but it will be garbage-collected immediately anyway.