# How do you configure Texmaker to use LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, texmaker

I'm extending my use from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. However, LuaTeX does not seem to come pre-configured  in the Texmaker editor.

How does one configure Texmaker to use LuaTeX on a document-to-document basis?

(I am using ubuntu 10.4, but this question should be a priori platform independent.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to permanently switch from pdflatex to lualatex, see Joseph's answer. If, however, you want to be able to use both, you need to add a user-defined command. From the menu, User -> User commands -> Edit user commands opens a dialog box. Choose a name (eg "LuaLaTeX" for the command) and use `lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode %` for the command itself. This command is now available form the menu or as Alt+Shift+F1.

Normally, lualatex should be in your command search path (given by the `PATH` environment variable), but if it isn't, you need to specify the full path to lualatex. Check the path for pdflatex in the preferences: lualatex is most probably in the same directory.

Comment: The question doesn't exactly give away whether this is a permanent change or not :-)

Comment: minor suggestion for improving your answer, for completeness' sake: adding how (with which `terminal` command) to check/verify whether Lua's on `PATH`...

Answer (score 6):

From the Preferences menu entry (location platform-dependent), you should be able to change the 'PdfLaTeX' line changing `<path>/pdflatex` to `<path>/lualatex`. Usually, `<path>` will be something like `/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin`, or `/usr/texbin` on the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara). It is included in TeX Live from version 2012, so those with recently updated TeX Lives will have it available. Other users will have to install it manually.

To use `arara` from Texmaker see [Integration of arara in Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/integration-of-arara-in-texmaker/107995#107995). 
Having installed it, and configured Texmaker, one just has to add for example

```
% arara: lualatex
```

at the beginning of your file, and compile with `arara`. See [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation/77879#77879) for another example.

Answer (score 2):

I post this as a new answer because the latest version of TexMaker (4.1) supports this natively.

Options -> Configure TexMaker
Fast Compil -> Luatex

Answer (score 1):

Options > Configure Texmaker.

If you intend to replace `pdflatex` then I suggest you simply overwrite the *PdfLaTeX*-field with the appropriate command. Either that or you can specify a User Command (User > User Commands > Edit User Commands) and then invoke it from the same menu.

Keep in mind that if you're using a custom Quick Build you need to make sure it's replaced too, as just changing the PdfLaTeX field doesn't do this for you.