# How to type these special brackets in latex in text mode?

Tags: symbols, brackets

LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3010): 【

RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3011): 】

LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3016): 〖

RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3017): 〗

LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3018): 〘

RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3019): 〙

LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3014): 〔

RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3015): 〕

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Special bracket symbols are usually parts of math fonts. Do you *require* them to be output in text mode, or is math mode ok too?

Comment: @Mico I only need them in text mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbola or Droid Sans Fallback fonts support them, for example.

Compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229882/101651).

```
% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229882/101651
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\mysym}[1]{{\fontspec{Symbola}\symbol{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\mysymb}[1]{{\fontspec{Droid Sans Fallback}\symbol{#1}}}

\begin{document} 
Symbola:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3010) & \mysym{"3010}\\
RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3011) & \mysym{"3011}\\
LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3016) &
\mysym{"3016}\\
RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3017) &
\mysym{"3017}\\
LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3018) & \mysym{"3018}\\
RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3019) & \mysym{"3019}\\
LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3014) & \mysym{"3014}\\
RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3015) & \mysym{"3015}\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{10pt}Droid Sans Fallback:

\begin{tabular}{ll}
LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3010) & \mysymb{"3010}\\
RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3011) & \mysymb{"3011}\\
LEFT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3016) &
\mysymb{"3016}\\
RIGHT WHITE LENTICULAR BRACKET (U+3017) &
\mysymb{"3017}\\
LEFT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3018) & \mysymb{"3018}\\
RIGHT WHITE TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3019) & \mysymb{"3019}\\
LEFT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3014) & \mysymb{"3014}\\
RIGHT TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET (U+3015) & \mysymb{"3015}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't I use it with PDFLaTex? I tried using LuaLaTex on Texmaker using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5425/181103) but I still get an error.

Comment: @Perlinpinpin No, the `fontspec` package requires either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, it doesn't work with pdfLaTeX. Which error do you get?

Comment: "fontspec error: font-not-found!! The font 'Symbola' cannot be found. See the fontspec documentation." I used XeLaTex.

Comment: @Perlinpinpin Then you don't have that font installed, you have to search here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3010/fontsupport.htm a font installed on your system.

Comment: I changed the code to `\newcommand*{\mysym}[1]{{\fontspec{Times New Roman}\symbol{#1}}}`. I'm not getting any error but the output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veVEV.png).

Comment: @Perlinpinpin you have to use a font which supports these symbols, look at the list in the link I posted before.