# Bibtex, Latex compiling

Tags: bibtex

On several occations I have read instructions like "run Latex on your file, then run Bibtex, and afterwards run Latex again..." . I am using TeXstudio as editor and when compiling any tex-code I simply press the compile-button. What happens behind this did not matter to me as the pdf I wanted was created anyway. Now that I am using `.bib` files for referencing, I am having a problem where the solution to this was the same as above. But how do I do it? I only know the compile-button. How can I run Latex individually from Bibtex and Bibtex individually from Latex? And which of both is running when simply pressing "compile"?

Comment: I do have a suspicion: pressing compile button = Latex, pressing F11 = running Bibtex . At least it's doing what I want.

Comment: It sounds as if compile button = pdfLaTeX. But this probably depends on how you have configured your editor. Most editors have options (buttons or items in menus) which let you choose other compilation options e.g. bibTeX or biber. If you are using `biblatex`, you probably need to use biber. If you are using `bibtex`, you definitely need to use bibtex. [You can use bibtex with `biblatex` but it is not default.]

Comment: how can you not using bibtex when using bibtex? I mean, you use what you configure, right?

Comment: What I mean is: if you have written your document using bibtex commands (e.g. `\bibliographystyle{}`), then you need to do pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex. If you have written it using `biblatex` (`\usepackage{biblatex}`) then, by default, you need biber: pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex. So what you use to compile in the second step depends on how you are managing things in your document.

Comment: how can I give you a reputation point for this answer?

Comment: You can't ;). It is a comment - not an answer. And it does not answer your question! (If it did answer your question, you could ask me to write it as an answer and then you could accept it.)

Comment: no chat! @cfr: yes please, as answer. It helps others as clarification. I would have been glad to read this anywhere before in the internet.

Comment: Chat? I only answered your question!

Comment: @cfr: sorry, there was a message above the comment asking if the discussion should be moved to chats.

Comment: Oh, yes. That's very annoying. Especially since if you agree, it often tells you that one person or the other doesn't have enough reputation to chat! But then it keeps bugging you about it...

Comment: As an aside, I'd highly recommend using the `arara` build tool.  It will simplify the process of building even further and will (as a side-effect) record the basic compilation steps as part of the file :)

Comment: Jesus christ. I have been looking all over for this exact solution. Your comment about F11 fixed everything. I guess I should add a bibtex button to my texstudio set up.

Comment: See also [compiling - Compile LaTeX with BibTeX and glossaries - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/compile-latex-with-bibtex-and-glossaries)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The 'compile' button is running a default compilation sequence. It sounds as if this is probably pdfLaTeX in your case. (You can probably change this if you wanted - many editors allow you to customise the default.)

To generate your bibliography, you need to look at what is in your document. How are you managing references? If you use commands such as

```
\bibliographystyle{stylename}
\bibliography{bibfilename}
```

Then you need to run

- `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`

If you have something like this:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfilename.bib}% or \bibliography{bibfilename}
...
\printbibliography
```

Then you need to run

- `pdflatex` -> `biber` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`

It is possible to use `bibtex` with `biblatex` but it is not default. Unless you have

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

you don't need to worry about this. If you do use this option, you would use the `bibtex` compilation sequence above rather than the `biber` one.

To run the compilations, you can either use the command line or your editor. Most editors have buttons or menus with options for non-default compilation. Even though pdfLaTeX is default, there is probably a button or menu option for bibTeX (and perhaps biber). You can probably customise things further to suit your work-flow.

Comment: If getting `file.aux` not found when using `pdflatex`, replace those calls with `latex` and call `pdflatex` after you complete the sequence.

Answer (score 28):

Here's a trick I like to use:

1. Create a python script in the root directory of your project, called e.g. `compile_refs.py` and paste the following code into it:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   import subprocess, sys

   commands = [
       ['pdflatex', sys.argv[1] + '.tex'],
       ['bibtex', sys.argv[1] + '.aux'],
       ['pdflatex', sys.argv[1] + '.tex'],
       ['pdflatex', sys.argv[1] + '.tex']
   ]

   for c in commands:
       subprocess.call(c)
   ```
2. When you want to compile references you just run: `python compile_refs.py main_file_name`.

Comment: You should look into [`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara).

Answer (score 11):

Here's a useful `Makefile` you can use to automate the compiling process described in the [answer by cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204298/59592):

```
DOCNAME=report

all: report

.PHONY: clean

report:
    pdflatex $(DOCNAME).tex
    bibtex $(DOCNAME).aux
    pdflatex $(DOCNAME).tex
    pdflatex $(DOCNAME).tex

view: report
    open $(DOCNAME).pdf

clean:
    rm *.blg *.bbl *.aux *.log
```

Just paste this into a file called `Makefile` in the same directory as your main .tex file and replace `report` in the variable definition `DOCNAME=report` with whatever your file is named.

Then you can use this as follows:

1. `make` or `make report` will create the PDF doc from the TeX sources.
2. `make view` will make the PDF if not already created and open it with your system default PDF viewer.
3. `make clean` will clean up the intermediate files created during PDF creation.

If you need to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`, you can just replace the call to `bibtex` with a call to `biber`.

Comment: additionally for biber, you must use `$(DOCNAME).bcf` instead

Comment: You should include `view` in the `.PHONY` targets.

Comment: When making this `Makefile`, make sure to use tabs and not spaces.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution: [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/?lang=en). I can't say it works in all cases, but for some basic setting (thesis, paper), it works well.

Here is an example extracted from its man-doc (e.g. you have `thesis.tex` in your current folder):

```
latexmk thesis
```

> --> run latex enough times to resolve cross-references

```
latexmk -pvc -ps thesis
```

> --> run latex enough times to resolve cross-references, make a postscript file, start a previewer.
>   Then watch for changes in the source file thesis.tex and any files it uses.
>   After any changes rerun latex the appropriate number of times and remake the postscript file.
>   If latex encounters an error, latexmk will keep running, watching for source file changes.

```
latexmk -c
```

> --> remove .aux, .log, .bbl, .blg, .dvi, .pdf, .ps & .bbl files

So with one command, we can make `latexmk` works in the **interactive** mode, every change in .tex or event .bib file will be re-complied automatically. More detailed docuement [here](http://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html).

Answer (score 2):

IF YOU ARE USING TEXSTUDIO. Go To :
settings --> compilations and run by waiting the excution of every step :

1 pdflatex. --> 2 bibtex . --> 3 pdflatex .  --> 4  pdflatex .

Answer (score 2):

Building on the top answer, here's my simple script to do it for BibTex:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE="${1%.*}"
pdflatex $BASE.tex
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Compilation error. Check log."
    exit 1
fi
bibtex $BASE
pdflatex $BASE.tex
pdflatex $BASE.tex
exit 0
```

Which I run with `./latexcompile.sh mytexdoc` (note the lack of file extension).

Don't forget to do `chmod +x latexcompile.sh` to make it executable!