# Error warnings or searches in JabRef?

Tags: jabref

I have a tex-document and wrote a bib-file with JabRef. However, the bibliography does not compile, after the usual LaTeX and bibliography compilationcommands.

Is there a way for JabRef to identify errors I may have made in writing up the bibliography?

Comment: Start compiling  [some working example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604).  Once you are sure that you have not problem in these examples, it is easy to check if the problem is in the .tex file or in the .bib file, and in this case, it is trivial add a particular entry to the .bib example and check if that reference have error.  Sometimes, read the compilation messages and the .log file also help to locate the problem.

Comment: If you exported the bib file with JabRef, I'd guess that there is hardly a way for JabRef to tell whether there are any mistakes in the syntax. You should post at least the error message you get when compiling the document. This would help us point you in the right direction where to look for the error. The best would, of course be, that you could provide an MWE. In such situations, trying to creating an MWE often already helps to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the errors are not related to JabRef, nor to your .bib file.
It may be due to the way you compile your document.

You need to compile first with LaTeX (as you did, and it is normal at this point to get question marks), then with BibTeX, then with LaTeX again (one or two times).

See [Bibtex, Latex compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204291/bibtex-latex-compiling)

Comment: That is what I did, and unfortunately it nevertheless  does not compile. I will edit so that the question expresses this.