# Add post processing step with VS Code

Tags: texlive, glossaries, makeindex, vscode

I'm very new to Latex and I'm trying to setup a glossary. I need to execute a post processing step, but I can't find how can I add this command to the compilation using VS Code. The command is:

```
makeindex -s template.ist -t template.glg -o template.gls template.glo -s "%tm.ist" -t "%tm.glg" -o "%tm.gls" "%tm.glo"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your settings.json
2. Under `"latex-workshop.latex.tools"` add a new entry with your desired post-processing operation. The arguments and command depend on what you want to do, in my case it's generating a glossary so I just need the following:

```
        {
            "name": "makeglossaries",
            "command": "makeglossaries",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
```

3. Under `"latex-workshop.latex.recipes"` add a new entry. The order of the elements in "tools" is very important. In this case `makeglossaries` could go after or before `bibtex`, [it doesn't really matter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/compile-latex-with-bibtex-and-glossaries?rq=1):

```
        {
            "name": "pdflatex ➞ makeglossaries ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex × 2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "makeglossaries",
                "bibtex",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
```

4. Press `CTRL+S` to save your settings.
5. Now press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` to open the command palette. Search for `LaTeX Workshop: Build with recipe` and select your recipe. Done.