# how to cause unix 'make' to know how many times to run *tex

Tags: makefile

Is there a clever way to cause the unix `make` command to run a tex variant as many times as are required to resolve all references?  I've used tex for a long time, and I still don't know which of all those extra files (`.aux`, `.log`, etc) should be checked, so I usually just run (pdf)latex 3 times, but that is slow for a 400 page document.  I am thinking that a fragment such as the line below might be a starting point ... maybe I should just string 3 or so of these together?

```
(pdflatex oar | grep -vq 'here were undefined references')
```

Comment: Also have a look at the answers on a related question about [automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used in the past this [Makefile](https://web.archive.org/web/20061205102406/http://snovae.in2p3.fr/ycopin/soft/Makefile.latex), from [Yannick Copin](http://snovae.in2p3.fr/ycopin/).

But, I guess [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) also has some advantage over `make` (although I like using custom `Makefile`).

Comment: @Yannick: Thanks.  I like `make` because I'm doing a lot of extra things in there, besides the *tex work.  Maybe I should use `latexmk` and `make` together, though.

Comment: @dan, definitely, having `make` use `latexmk` to build *tex documents is the way to go.

Comment: @dan Yes, I also use custom Makefile for compiling extra stuff (like Asymptote code) and calling external program, e.g. pdfnup. Never tried to combine latexmk and make, though.

Comment: It's a pity that the link to the `Makefile` example is broken now (Forbidden response), so that we cannot study this answer and learn something.

Answer (score 8):

You also get an undefined reference, when it is an unknown one ...

You can delete the time stamp line from the logfile and then build the md5 sum or whatever. When it didn't change then you have no changes in the document. You can also speedup your compilation time, when you do not build a pdf in the first or two run:
`pdflatex -draftmode ...`, then only the `aux|idx|...-files` will be created to get correct labels/references.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about ``-draftmode``.  It speeds up my compilation by 10 percent.

Comment: +1 for `-draftmode` .

Comment: (+1) All good things to know, thx.

Answer (score 2):

See [latexmake](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexmake/) and [UltimateLatexMakefile](https://web.archive.org/web/20130616081236/http://www.acoustics.hut.fi/u/mairas/UltimateLatexMakefile/) for instance. See also [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation).