# How to precisely tell from log-file whether to rerun LaTeX

Tags: compiling

There is a bit of discussion in related questions about automated LaTeX (re)compilation (e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8317/how-to-cause-unix-make-to-know-how-many-times-to-run-tex)) and elsewhere on the web on rerunning the `latex` command in order to resolve all references.

Now how can I precisely determine from visual inspection (or a search query) in the `log`-file whether all references are resolved? That is, what is the *precise* set of messages that indicates that there are unresolved references? A regular-expression-like answer will be good.

(I know that I can mine the solutions to the above-cited SE.TeX post for an educated guess of an answer, but it seems like having an expert answer this and having that answer in one place in this forum will be useful for many people.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common, standard "rerun warning" from LaTeX is:

> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

However, other messages may also occur and is most likely package dependent.

[`rerunfilecheck`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rerunfilecheck) under PDFLaTeX provides you to tailor the rerun warning using `\RerunFileCheck`.

Comment: My log-file contains the text *"<some path>\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)*; I think `hyperref` loads this. Towards the end of my log-file I get text like this: *Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `<my source filename>.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: <some checksum>.* Is this a definitive indication that no rerun is necessary?

Comment: From the [`rerunfilecheck` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.pdf): "Since version 1.30.0 pdfTeX provides `\pdfmdfivesum` and `\pdffilesize`. These features are also available in LuaTeX, provided by package [`pdftexcmds`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds). Thus this package `rerunfilecheck` uses these features to detect file changes. This saves the packages from keeping the whole files in memory or in file copies. The drawback are different files with the same size and the same MD5 checksum (seldom, hopefully)."

Comment: Thanks for the info - now I would say that having the same MD5 checksum for manually edited source files of identical size is a negligible practical problem (though it's good that it's being mentioned explicitly). My intended question was whether constancy of the `out`-file is a definitive/reliable indication of one not needing to rerun the `latex` command. Is it?

Comment: You're probably referring to the `.log` file. Even the `.log` file carries a time/date stamp of the compile and is therefore not "consistent".

Comment: Actually, I meant the `out`-file, because that one appears in my setup (with `hyperref`) in the output that's written to the log-file: see the "Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `<my source filename>.out' has not changed."-message cited in my first comment in this thread.

Comment: @user14996, constancy of the .out file means only that. There could be other files that have changed. You can keep track of a larger set of these (but not necessarily all of them), by loading `rerunfilecheck` with options: `\usepackage[mainaux,starttoc,partaux]{rerunfilecheck}`

Comment: If/when you have time, [latexmk](http://ctan.tug.org/pkg/latexmk) may provide a good alternative solution where you just "don't have to worry".

Comment: You wrote: "However, other messages may also occur [...]". What are some common examples of other messages?

Comment: @user14996: See my answer in [How can I force LyX to rebuild intermediate files for clean PDF display?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73138/5764) that shows a different warning issued by [`etaremune`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etaremune). Others may also exist.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Good to know, but if (according to the discussion in this comment thread) it is *that* hard for a user to *definitively* determine whether LaTeX has finished running, the question is how `latexmk` could possibly do this.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I think it's one of those *computers can do lots of boring repetitive things that humans aren't good at* kind of things...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough One question is also whether it'd been determined/proven that `latexmk` *actually* definitively determines this. If this has been documented, perhaps someone familiar with this subject matter can add a link or more details here.