# running biblatex-biber with xelatex (editor:notepad++; distro: miktex)

Tags: xetex, biblatex, biber

i would like to set up a workflow that uses biblatex-biber with `xelatex`, on `notepad++`. the `backend=biber` in the `biblatex` environment. can someone explain the command line sequence to me? as i understand it, you run `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex`, `xelatex`. what files are the arguments for each of those commands?

so, assuming i'm trying to compile and then output to PDF a file foo.tex, the sequence would be

```
xelatex foo.tex
biber ?
xelatex ?
xelatex ?
```

Answer (score 4):

`biblatex` is a package to be loaded in the preamble of your `.tex` document; biber is a program to be run separate from (Xe)LaTeX. The correct minimum compiling sequence is

```
xelatex foo(.tex)
biber foo(.bcf)
xelatex foo(.tex)
```

i.e. one XeLaTeX run less than if one would use traditional BibTeX instead of biber (and not use biblatex).

(I can't comment on the suitability of notepad++ for compiling `.tex` documents.)

EDIT: Added optional file extensions (`.tex`, `.bcf`).

EDIT 2: Last but not least, before you start to write your own makefile, have a look at [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation).