# Is there software similar to the arXiv.org AutoTeX?

Tags: automation, arxiv, archiving

I was wondering, does software similar to the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) AutoTeX exist, or is AutoTeX is available somewhere?

Comment: A quick google search shows [TeX::AutoTeX](http://search.cpan.org/~tschwand/TeX-AutoTeX-v0.906.0/lib/TeX/AutoTeX.pm) perl module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, it's simply a script that runs LaTeX the right number of times on the source files --- there are similar alternatives around, such as [latexmk](http://latex-mk.sourceforge.net/) (the most mature), [latex-makefile](http://code.google.com/p/latex-makefile/), or [rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber) (my personal favorite, although it is complicated to google for help, given the unfortunate naming).

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64

Answer (score 12):

arXiv runs AutoTeX which is available via a cpan module: http://search.cpan.org/~tschwand/TeX-AutoTeX-v0.906.0/lib/TeX/AutoTeX/File.pm

We also ad hoc apply hyperref to your code by default. arXiv's tex tree is currently built off of TeXLive2011. If your code compiles without human intervention from the liveDVD image, it will compile on arXiv just fine.

Cheers,
-arXiv admin

Comment: Hi Jake, just off topic here, where does one ask LaTeX related arXiv questions? I don't use arXiv my self but a lot of my users does and sometimes they get into problems.

Comment: sorry for getting back to this so late... specific questions should be directed to help@arxiv.org along with a submit-id that has the source code in it. For other contact info see: https://arxiv.org/help/contact