# How to automate typeset proceess?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, automation, texworks

I am currently using Texworks + Linux.
To compile the PDF I hit pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex + pdflatex.
Is there a way so that I create a new typeset that does that in one click?

Found the easy answer:

1- add a new typeset tool, (Edit > Preferences > Typesetting > Add Processing tools)

[image: typeseting]

2- And use Browse to add your simple bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                 

filename=$1                                                                 
filename_bib=$2                                                             

pdflatex $filename                                                          
bibtex $filename_bib                                                        
pdflatex $filename                                                          
pdflatex $filename
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use `arara` :)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59077/automating-compilation?rq=1 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution to the problem rather than an answer to the question (as I understand it), I'd recommend using `arara`.

There's very good integration documentation available in [`arara`'s critically-acclaimed manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/arara/doc/arara-usermanual.pdf), chapter 4.

Essentially, you place a few lines at the top of your TeX document like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{…
```

and then run

```sh
$ arara my-file.tex
```

and `arara` will understand those first few lines and do what you want.  Those first few lines come with options, too, but that's for the documentation to explain :)

---

As @cfr points out, it's also extensible!  You can add your own rules to arara and share them if you can't find what you're looking for.  (I *believe* those types of questions would be on-topic here, but I'm not certain.)

Comment: And you can add custom thingies. Also for the documentation to explain. But neat.