# Convert LaTeX compilation from multiple run throughs to single compilation

Tags: compiling

I have a simple question about using LaTeX. I often have to do pdf2Latex several times and with a Bibtex thrown in there somewhere to get my document to come out correctly.

More or less looks like

```
latex A.tex
bibtex B
latex A.tex
latex A.tex
```

Is there anyway to do that all in one go? I am using WinEdt 7.0 if that matters

Answer (score 4):

Latex depends upon several runs to get things right, it would take very major surgery to the code to change this.

You may want something like a Makefile to manage the multiple passes.  See, e.g.,  [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation) for some posssibilties.