# Author not appearing

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

I've properly set the reference in the `.bib` file but still getting author problems:

```
Author undefined for the 'baeza1999modern' on page 1
```

In my `ref.bib`, I do have an entry:

```
@book{baeza1999modern,
  title={Modern information retrieval},
  author={Baeza-Yates, Ricardo and Ribeiro-Neto, Berthier and others},
  volume={463},
  year={1999},
  publisher={ACM press New York.}
}
```

In LaTeX, the text is

```
As coupled by ~\citet{baeza1999modern},
```

I want to get something like `Baeza-Yates et al.`. However, it is appearing like

[image]

The error I am getting is

```
Author undefined for citation`baeza1999modern' (natbib) on page 1
```

Any idea?

---

Ok, currently I have a solution which allow me at least to continue working,

I added this in the preamble,

```
\usepackage[numbers, square]{natbib}
```

and this `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

So, currently the `et al` is being displayed properly, the citation is appearing like `[2,1]`.

It would have been better if it was like `[Sin01,ADV10]`; any suggestion?

Comment: Are you running the usual sequence `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` on your file?  (I'd also change the `... by ~\citet` to `... by~\citet`, but that is only for aesthetic reasons.)

Comment: for the 4 commands you listed, is not there a single command that does all, actually, i'm using texmaker

Comment: According to [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402/5764), it's unsure whether TeXmaker has a project manager. However, it does seem to distinguish between a "Quick Build" and "something else." That something else, I assume, would allow you to compile using a sequence that could include `bibtex`.

Comment: For automatic compilation, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation Latexmk and arara. You could also set up a quick build or user command that runs all four.

Comment: even though I'm running the sequence latex, bibtex, latex, latex, i'm still getting the same problem

Comment: You can configure Texmaker to run latex, bibtex, latex, latex on quickbuild. It's under Options >> Configure Texmaker >> Quick Build. There you can determine what to run on quickbuild. If there isn't the combination you want you can set a custom combination.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? It is the bibliography style that determines if (and how) the list of authors, in  citations of pieces with 3 or more authors, gets truncated to `FirstAuthor et al.`. Incidentally, are you sure you're referencing the piece you list in your example correctly? The reason I ask is that I'm pretty sure it has exactly two authors. Thus, the output of `\citet` on this piece should be `Baeza-Yates and Ribeiro-Neto (1999)`.

Comment: I have to use alpha and display only the first author

Comment: @Noor -- If you are still experiencing the same problem, it is time to provide a complete minimal example that others can copy to try to replicated (and then solve) the problem.

Comment: @jon, i added an example above

Comment: Your posted example complies fine in a standard set-up.  Please post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), rather than code snippets.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, can you please check my answer and improve on it if possible

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

A standard working set-up would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
As coupled by~\citet{baeza1999modern}, or perahps \citeauthor{baeza1999modern}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

with `ref.bib` as in your question.  This gives

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Suppose then I want to only use use \cite, how does it appear?? if i'm not mistaken, the whole et al appear then??

Comment: `\cite` behaves as `\citet` in this scheme.  The documentation of `natbib` advises against using `\cite`, suggesting that you should always use either `\citet` or `\citep` as appropriate.