# Problem displaying author in citation when using natbib's \citeauthor command

Tags: citing, natbib

I have problem displaying the author name in citation when using `natbib`. I wrote

`This is explained in \citeauthor{lamport94}`, and what I get is:

[image]

, and my entire code is given by:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
 \usepackage{natbib}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is explained in \citeauthor{lamport94}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{lamport94}   Leslie Lamport,   \emph{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}.   Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,   2nd Edition,   1994.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I wonder what is wrong?

Note:
I'm using LyX.
I'm aware of thread [Author not appearing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101853/author-not-appearing), but there's no resolution there, and I use `\citeauthor{}` insteand of `\citet{}`.

Comment: With natbib the bibliography entry must have a specific format  (so that natbib can extract the author information) which is described in the documentation. (2.2 The Syntax of the thebibliography).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I see. By the way, if I use Bibtex the problem will disappear ?

Comment: Only if you use a bibliography style which is adapted to natbib and so "produce" correct entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the command `\citeauthor`, which is provided by the `natbib` citation management package, only makes sense if you use an *authoryear-style* citation method. However, you're loading the `natbib` package with the `numbers` option, i.e., you're telling it to use a *numeric-style* citation method.

Hence, if you want to use numeric-style citations, don't use `\citeauthor`. Aside: When `natbib` is loaded with the `numbers` option, the command `\citet` is modified to behave like `\cite` and will thus create a numeric-style rather than an authoryear-style callout to the piece in question. However, the `\citeauthor` command isn't aliased to `\cite` when the `numbers` option is set, and that's why you're receiving the error message you're reporting.

Alternatively, if you do wish to use authoryear-style citations along with the `natbib` package, you should (i) *not* specify the `numbers` option when loading the `natbib` package and (ii) augment the entry in the `thebibliography` environment to include the optional argument `[Lamport (1994)]`, as is done in the following modified form of your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor{lamport94}

\citet{lamport94}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Lamport (1994)]{lamport94}Leslie Lamport,   \emph{\LaTeX: 
   A Document Preparation System}.   Addison Wesley, Massachusetts,   
   2nd Edition,   1994.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem in my MWE is that I only have `\bibitem{lamport94} ...` instead of `\bibitem[Lamport (1994)]{lamport94}`. I've tried that the `\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}` still allow me to use `\citeauthor{}`

Comment: @user26939 - I'm glad you've found a workable solution. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept answers that you found useful. :-)

Comment: Ok, done ! ....

Comment: Nearly 10 years after I posted this answer, a downvote. Wow. To the anonymous downvoter:  Care to step forward and explain hour action?