# How do I run this poster template?

Tags: posters

I found a *really* nice example [here](http://andreas.welcomes-you.com/projects/a0poster/) that I would like to get going with as a template. There are *some* instructions but I found that errors in my document from what I can follow.

- I downloaded `a0poster.cls` and `a0header.ps` (I have no idea what these are) and I put them in the file where I would like my `.tex` file to go (this location was a guess).
- I downloaded `a0size.sty` and did the same with that.
- The website says that I also need `multicol, pstricks and pst-grad` packages.

I ignored this for the time-being and downloaded the `poster.tex` file (as well as `gklogo.eps` and `poster.bib`) just to see what happened first. I got a lot of errors!

The error at the top of the list is "Undefined control sequence.  \c@lor@to@ps \background {1.1.1.}{1.1.1.}{0.5}"

I'm clearly out of my depth but I can't stand going back to PowerPoint, where can I start in getting this template to work?

Comment: `"Undefined control sequence. \c@lor@to@ps` should be read as `you are using pdflatex and you need to use latex`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using TeXMaker. If I change to 'compile LaTeX' I get no errors but nothing loads.

Comment: nothing loads where? latex should make a dvi file then you need to run dvips to get a postscript file then ps2pdf to get a pdf,

Comment: Wow. It actually worked it in one attempt, this is new for me

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way to automate the `LaTeX` `DVI-PS` `PS-PSF` `View PDF` process?

Comment: yes lots, your texmaker ide may have something built in (I wouldn't know) or several tools latexmk, arara, rubber, ...  I'll ping the author of arara who's lurking in the chat room....

Comment: @User17670 To configure arara,what's your OS and TeX distribution (TeXlive or MiKTeX)? meanwhile you can go through [arara screenshot guide,page 33](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/arara/arara-usermanual.pdf). BTW [Paulo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) is author of arara

Comment: I am using Texmaker on Win7. I've just gone `Options > Configure Texmaker > Quick Build` then I selected `LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF` from the list, so now I just press `F1` and I get full compilation and output!

Comment: @User17670 Yes TeXmaker has that advantages,there are many ways to do this using [latex automation tools](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/15717), feel free to ask questions on TeX.SX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pstricks` requires a PostScript interpreter at some point in the document production (there is a hint in the name) so while there are packages to give access to parts of its functionality from pdflatex (by executing external programs in the background) its natural workflow is `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.  The `\c@lor@to@ps` error commonly occurs when the `dvips` back end of the color package has not been loaded (because pdftex has been detected).