# LaTeX plus BibTeX but don't work in TeXworks

Tags: bibtex

I have Googled a lot about how to make it work. This is what I have now:

I have `IEEEtran.bst, mybibfile.bib` and `test.tex` all located in the same folder.

This is `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

\cite{sample1234}Hello world.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran.bst}
\bibliography{mybibfile.bib}


\end{document}
```

This is `mybibfile.bib`:

```
@book{sample1234,
  title={Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables},
  author={Abramowitz, M. and Stegun, I. A.},
  edition = {9th edition},
  year={1964},
  publisher={Dover}
}
```

And I press the "Typeset" green arrow button on the TeXworks editor in the following sequence:

`tex`, `bib`, `tex`, `tex`

After this, the generated "paper" looks like:

```
[?]Hello world.
```

Now there are these files in the same folder:

```
IEEEtran.bst
mybibfile.bib
```

`mybibfile.log` --> This file is empty

```
test.aux
```

`test.log`  --> This file is not empty

```
test.pdf
test.synctex.gz
test.tex
```

My TeXworks version is 0.4.4, and the MiKTeX version is 2.9.

I spent a whole night on it.

EDIT: something suspicious in `test.log`:

```
(C:\TUT\BSHE\LATEXBIB\test.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `sample1234' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.

No file test.bbl.
[1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\myfolder\test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77879/5239)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing `\bibliography{mybibfile.bib}` with `\bibliography{mybibfile}`. The extension is not needed and may be in the way.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem too. Firstly, I pressed the green button on .tex pdflatex, then I pressed the green button on .bib bibtex. and then .tex pdflatex and again. That's why there is no bbl. Then I noticed it says the text.bbl not found, so I change the second press - I pressed the button in .tex but with pdflatex changed into bibtex. Then the bbl is generated but it is empty. After I deleted the .bib as you commented, everything works. (With Lauri that I did this) :D