# How can I do the 'latex bibtex latex latex' compiling using Windows without the command line?

Tags: compiling, windows, automation

I'm using LaTeX and JabRef on Windows. I set up my bibliography database and cited references in my LaTeX document. However, I do not know how to use the command line on Windows to do the 'latex bibtex latex latex' compile. So my question is: **How can I do the 'latex bibtex latex latex' compiling using Windows without the command line?**

Comment: Which editor do you use for writing your LaTeX document? Most LaTeX editors, such as TeXworks (included in MikTeX and TeX Live) have features for running both `pdflatex` and `bibtex`.

Comment: I'm using the TeXworks editor. How can I do the compiling with this?

Comment: this question was made for `arara` :) have a look at [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64). Welcome!

Comment: As an aside, the command line is very simple for things such as this.  All you really need is `cd` (*c*hange *d*irectory) and `pdflatex` itself.  See [this short introduction](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/) for more detailed info and screenshots.  The command to compile a LaTeX document is `pdflatex mydocument.tex`.  That said, this can become a pretty mundane process, so there are a **ton** of tools available for the task.  Your editor will likely help you here.

Comment: With the drop-down menu next to the compile button you can choose which tool to use, BibTeX is on the list. If you're using MikTeX, you'll also find an entry called *pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+Bibtex*, if you use this, then all the necessary compilations will be done automatically, without you having to switch tool and click again.

Comment: Based on your comment, I've voted to close it as a duplicate of [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64) Please let us know if that's not ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in the preamble of your document:

```
\immediate\write18{bibtex \jobname}
```

It runs `bibtex` every time you typeset your document.

It has the advantage that it doesn't need separate run of `bibtex`, but with the disadvantage that it runs `bibtex` even when it is not required: not every time it is necessary to run bibtex, but only when a new citation or change in citation order happens.

Beware that `shell-escape` needs to be enabled for this code to perform. `shell-escape` is enabled via

```
pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex
```

Comment: This doesn't really flow well with an anti-command-line workflow...