# nomencl package doesn't allow exclamation marks in keys

Tags: indexing, nomenclature

I am using the `nomencl` package, and so far it has worked out flawlessly. However, today I decided to introduce some notation that includes an exclamation mark, and it failed.

There is a minimal example here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$n!$}{factorial of $n$}
\[
 n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i
\]
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

- `pdflatex text.tex` runs OK
- `makeindex test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o test.nls` runs OK, and reports "1 entries accepted, 0 rejected)", etc (no problem).
- `pdflatex text.tex`, ran for the second time after `makeindex`, fails.

The error is this:

```
Writing nomenclature file test.nlo
(./test.aux) (./test.nls
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6     \subitem
                 [{$n
?
```

If I remove the exclamation mark, like this:

```
\nomenclature{$n$}{factorial of $n$}
```

then the document compiles and produces the correct output.

I have tried using `$n{!}$` and `$n\!$`, but that didn't fix the problem.

What would be the right way to include $n!$, or $!n$, or other expressions with
exclamation marks in nomenclature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`!` is a special character for MakeIndex (that is used for sorting the nomenclature). Quote it with MakeIndex's method, that is, adding `%` in front of it:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$n%!$}{factorial of $n$}
\[
 n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i
\]
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

I added the suitable `arara` calls for taking care of the nomenclature. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77879/4427 for more information and links about `arara`.

**Note.** Before 2018, the quote character was `"` instead of `%`. The change makes it impossible to hide such nomenclature entries in macros, so beware.

Comment: I'm still having this issue with the exclamation mark. Saved your code as main.tex file and then I ran
pdflatex main.tex /
makeindex main.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o main.nls /
pdflatex main.tex
But I got the same error OP had.

Comment: @JulioCesar For very mysterious reasons, `nomencl.ist` now has `%` as the quote character. See edited answer.