# How to build Knitr document from the command line

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I would like to compile a knitr document from the command line.  With Sweave, the sequence

```
R CMD Sweave my_sweave_file.Rnw
latex my_sweave_file.tex
latex my_sweave_file.tex
dvips my_sweave_file.dvi
ps2pdf my_sweave_file.ps
```

builds the final pdf file I want to publish.  What is the corresponding build sequence with knitr?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**With the command line with `Sweave`:**

Really you need only two steps for a simple document as this `my_sweave_file.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text
<<RTest>>=
2+2
@
\end{document}
```

From the command line is enough:

```
R CMD Sweave my_sweave_file.Rnw
pdflatex my_sweave_file.tex
```

Or even only one:

```
R CMD Sweave --pdf my_sweave_file.Rnw
```

In case that you have cross-references (`\ref` or `\cite` commands, table of contents, index, glossaries, etc.) this  will not enough, so you must also compile  the generated  `.tex` file with the appropriate tools and rerun `pdlatex` as needed. See [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation) if you have some problem with the compilation sequences.

**With the command line with `knitr`:**

A compilation of a simple document could be done with:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('my_sweave_file.Rnw')"
pdflatex my_sweave_file.tex
```

Obviously, in complex Latex documents, you will need to add some compilation steps as above.

**Without the command line**

For the sake of completeness, an easy way to compile LateX+R documents is to work with LyX instead of LaTeX directly, loading the `Sweave` or  `Rnw(knitr)` modules,  making automatically in both case the "R Noweb" (`.Rnw`) to LaTeX exportation, and all the compilation steps of the LaTeX file.

Another possibility is use Rstudio to edit the .Rnw file and just push the PDF icon with the "Compile PDF" label. It is worth mention that you use also here Rmarkdown files (.Rmd extension) that offer the simplified syntax of markdown for text but can be converted as well to a LaTeX PDF. In this in case the compilation icon in changed by a is done by a dropdown menu "Knit" where you can select "Knit to PDF", with an obvious meaning.

**Warning**: The  MWE without R chunk options options can be compiled equally with  `Sweave` and `knit` functions, but there are chunk options specific for each of these functions: Some options cannot be used with `knitr` and many `knitr` options cannot be used  with the older `Sweave`, so actually is preferable use `knitr`.

Comment: You should really use a tool like `latexmk` or `texi2pdf` to run LaTeX (and, if necessary, BibTeX) as often as it needs to resolve all references.

Comment: @krlmlr, of course. Depending on what you have in LaTeX, you will need (or not) run `pdflatex` two or more times, may be also `bibtex`, or `biber`, or `makeglosssaries`, or `makeindex`, among others, manually, or with the help of tools as `arara`,`rubber`, your script, etc. But as OP is related with R and not the LateX features, my answer show the *minimum* working example. However, I will edit the answer to clarify the issue, thanks.

Comment: @Fran, thank you for your solution.  I found that RStudio has a convenient editor to use with Knitr, as Yihui suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The knitr package has a utility `knit2pdf`. Assuming you have R installed, the R command would be

```r
# within R
knitr::knit2pdf('my_file.Rnw')
```

In a shell, this would then be

```
$
Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('my_file.Rnw')"
```