# How can I use a table generated by Latex in R(xtable)?

Tags: r, xtable

I have a LaTeX table generated by Excel. I want to place this table but not as a LaTeX code, but rather as a xtable. It is possible to convert LaTeX to xtable?

Comment: If the table was generated by Excel, wouldn't it be better to use R to read the Excel file directly? Is this really a LaTeX question?

Comment: What mean "not as LaTeX code but rather as a xtable"? A *xtable is just LaTeX code*  generated by R, instead of an ouput in plain text. Your problem is [read the Excel in R directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099243/read-an-excel-file-directly-from-a-r-script) or after export to `.csv` text, assign to an object as `myexeceldata`, load the `xtable` library and then run `xtable(myexeceldata)` to obtain the LateX code, or simply run `myexeceldata` to obtain the table in plain text.

Comment: @Fran  your comment has benn very helpfully. Now, I have both  tables (generated in excel and also using the _xtable_ package) running in my _tex_ document.

Comment: @MarcoA.González, Glad to help. To leave the question as answered you could answer your own question to tell us your final  procedure, so others could learn from it (or improve, if possible). By the way, do you know about literate programming with Sweave or kintr? I think it might be very useful in this task.

Comment: @Fran Can you provide an answer to get if off the unanswered list? I don't even understand what the real problem is.

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't understand either, but as the question seem solved with my comment, I added an answer covering the Excel-xtable-LaTeX conversion.

Answer (score 4):

Set by step: Suppose that you have a `file.xlsx` that look like:

> [image: Excel file]

To convert to R, first export to `file.csv`:

```
,apples,tomatoes,babanas
Jinks,3,12,15
Pixie,4,5,6
Dixie,2,8,9
```

Then import as a data frame `mytable` in R:

```
> mytable <- read.table("file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",") 
> mytable

      X apples tomatoes babanas
1 Jinks      3       12      15
2 Pixie      4        5       6
3 Dixie      2        8       9
```

Or import directly from the `file.xlsx` (need  Perl installed on your system):

```
> library(gdata) 
> mytable  <- read.xls("file.xlsx")
```

The data frame obtained must be the same in any case. Just in case that first column are really row names as above:

```
> rownames(mytable) <- mytable[,1]
> mytable[,1] <- NULL
> mytable

      apples tomatoes babanas
Jinks      3       12      15
Pixie      4        5       6
Dixie      2        8       9
```

For convert the dataframe `mytable` as a xtable (that is, a chunk of LaTeX code):

```
> library(xtable) 
> xtable(mytable)

% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Mar 11 06:11:44 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & apples & tomatoes & babanas \\ 
  \hline
Jinks &   3 &  12 &  15 \\ 
  Pixie &   4 &   5 &   6 \\ 
  Dixie &   2 &   8 &   9 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

So you can copy & paste the ouput of R in your LaTeX file to obtain:

> [image: MWE2]

But the good thing of LaTeX+R is that you can make all the above automatically inserting a R chunk in your `file.tex` document (now is R noweb document, so save it as `file.Rnw`)  and compile it using `Sweave` or `knitr` from the command line (see 
[How to build Knitr document from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line) ) or simply making in Rstudio:

<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>New file</kbd> > <kbd>R Sweave</kbd> > Write some like:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Owners {\it \&} Fruits}
\author{Fran}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
<<mytable,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,results='hide'>>=
library(gdata) 
mytable  <- read.xls("file.xlsx")
rownames(mytable) <- mytable[,1]
mytable[,1] <- NULL
library(xtable) 
@
\section*{Introduction}
The cartoons (\Sexpr{row.names(mytable)}) are shooting fruits (\Sexpr{names(mytable)}). 
\lipsum[2] 
\section*{Cartoons have \Sexpr{sum(mytable$apples)} apples}
\lipsum[3]
<<xtable,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
print(xtable(mytable, caption="My Excel table"), caption.placement = "top")
@
\lipsum[4-15]
\end{document}
```

and finally, click on <kbd>Compile PDF</kbd> and you will obtain this `file.pdf`:

> [image: MWE]

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if you have a latex table `my_file.tex` such as:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Mar 11 06:11:44 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & apples & tomatoes & bananas \\ 
  \hline
Jinks & 3 & 1 & 15 \\ 
  Pixie & 4 & 5 & 6  \\ 
  Dixie & 2 & 8 & 9  \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

You can import it into R directly, such as:

```
library("data.table") # loads the smart "fast" fread function

#import data into R
data <- fread("my_file.tex", skip=8, sep="&", data.table=F) # skips in compatible lines
names <- read.table("my_file.tex", skip=6, nrow=1, sep="&", stringsAsFactors=F)

#remove latex symbols from header
names<-gsub("\\\\", "", as.character(names))
names<-gsub(" ", "", as.character(names))
colnames(data) <- names

remove latex end of line from last column
data[,ncol(data)]<-gsub("\\\\", "", as.character(data[,ncol(data)]))
data[,ncol(data)]<-gsub(" ", "", as.character(data[,ncol(data)]))
data[,ncol(data)] <- as.numeric(data[,ncol(data)]) #change type as desired
```

This returns the following from calling `data` in R:

```
     NA apples tomatoes bananas
1 Jinks      3        1      15
2 Pixie      4        5      6
3 Dixie      2        8      9
```

Note: *requires data.table 1.10.0 or higher*

You can also export this from R to LaTeX:

```
library("xtable")    
#function to export (filename defaults to object in R environment)
export_latex <- function(x, file) print(xtable(data.frame(x), type="latex", file=paste0(deparse(substitute(x)), ".tex"))
export_latex(data, file="my_file.tex")
```