# Add custom extensions and directives to arara

Tags: arara

This is a more general version of [Adam Liter's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175311/39222) about setting up an `arara` rule for `knitr`.

The basic question is this:

> *How can I enable support for customised extensions and directives in `araraconfig.yaml`?*

The answer would be straightforward if it were not that the documentation is apparently rather buggy. The problem is that using the syntax modelled in the manual results in the following error when `arara` is run:

```
I didn't find any directives in 'myfile.XXX', and so didn't do anything. Is that what you really wanted?
```

where `XXX` is the extension you tried to enable. Adam's question includes a fully documented example of the error for the case of `knitr`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution included in [Adam Liter's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175311/39222) worked for the case I was concerned with, as far as I can establish so far.

I am posting what I used to enable support for the `mp` extension in the hope that this will work more generally and/or help isolate the issue which Adam is still experiencing. Following discussion with Adam, we decided it was best to post a new generic question rather than including a more general answer in response to a `knitr`-specific question. (I cannot test the `knitr` bit.) Really, the solution here is all the result of Adam's efforts. I was just lucky enough to find that it worked perfectly with my configuration and for `metapost`.

Possibly relevant background information: I am using GNU/Linux with TeX Live 2013. (We don't know if it works for me because I use Linux or because I was concerned with `metapost`.)

Here is my `araraconfig.yaml`:

```
!config
paths:
- <arara> @{userhome}/.arara/rules
filetypes:
- extension: tex
- extension: mp
  pattern: ^(\s)*%\s+
- extension: dat
  pattern: ^(\s)*%\s+
- extension: dtx
- extension: ltx
- extension: sk
  pattern: ^(\s)*[%#]\s+
# vim: set nospell:
```

**Crucial note:** as Adam documents, you need `\s` where the documentation specifies `\\s`. (I am assuming `\s` means something like 'space' although the manual doesn't really explain this. Since regular expressions vary in syntax, this is a bit frustrating.)

This is the rule I am using for `metapost`. The rule is in `.arara/rules/mpost.yaml`:

```
!config
# metapost rule for arara
identifier: mpost
name: metapost
command: <arara> mpost @{action} @{options} "@{file}"
arguments:
- identifier: action
  flag: <arara> -interaction=@{parameters.action}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
# vim: set nospell:
```

I then add the following directive line in my `mp` source file:

```
% arara: mpost
```

This enables me to run either

```
arara figs.mp
```

or

```
arara figs
```

and have `arara` do the right thing. Either way, I get a 'success' and `figs.1` is produced. (That's the expected result in this case and converting to PDF shows that the result contains what I'd expect as well.)

Comment: (Sorry for the short comment, I am on mobile right now) There is an error in the documentation when telling you to use ‛\\s‛, it's actually ‛\s‛. I apologize for such error (and also for missing your question). I will add a new section about regex in the new manual, it sounds like a good plan. The upcoming version will hopefully provide a better control on extensions and rules in general. That is a good way to improve the tool: learning from its userbase. ‛:)‛

Comment: @PauloCereda Thanks for commenting. This question-and-answer was a follow up to another user's question and is really here to make the information hopefully a bit easier to find. I'm actually used to using regexes but everything uses a slightly different syntax and the documentation was so consistent, I tended to believe it!

Answer (score 2):

(Apologies if this would be better as a comment. I do not have sufficient reputation to post comments.)

The following rule seems to work well when called with just the base file name. It is also possible to have `arara` compile the Rnw source all the way to PDF with a single rule, see below.

```
!config
identifier: knitr
name: knitr
command: <arara> RScript -e "library(knitr); knit('"@{source}"', output='"@{target}"')"
arguments: 
- identifier: source
  flag: <arara> "@{parameters.source}"
  default: <arara> "@{getBasename(file)}".Rnw
- identifier: target
  flag: <arara> "@{parameters.target}"
  default: <arara> "@{getBasename(file)}".tex
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the error in the [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175311/how-to-write-an-arara-rule-for-knitr) when calling `arara` on my source Rnw file. In this case, `arara` complains that the file is not found. This is a problem with the rule above, because I want to call `arara` again to compile the .tex file to PDF. The directive

```
% arara: knitr
```

still exists as line 1 of the .tex file. Therefore, a subsequent call actually runs `arara` on the *source Rnw* file again, rather than what is intended. (I'm not sure why, since I have the Rnw extension listed last in my configuration file, reproduced below.) Of course one could edit the directive manually, but this is clumsy and inconvenient.

So we are still in need of a solution. Here is a simple workaround. This rule first calls `knitr`, then the `xelatex` engine.

```
!config
identifier: knitr
name: knitr
commands: 
- <arara> RScript -e "library(knitr); knit('"@{source}"', output='"@{target}"')"
- <arara> xelatex "@{target}"
arguments: 
- identifier: source
  flag: <arara> "@{parameters.source}"
  default: <arara> "@{getBasename(file)}".Rnw
- identifier: target
  flag: <arara> "@{parameters.target}"
  default: <arara> "@{getBasename(file)}".tex
```

Here is my configuration file that I am using with this rule.

```
!config
paths:
- <arara> /path/to/my/knitr/rule
filetypes:
- extension: tex
- extension: dtx
- extension: ltx
- extension: Rnw
  pattern: ^(\s)*%\s+
```

Comment: I am not sure if all your problems are solved. (It is up to you.) If not, consider update your situation by editing your original problem.

Comment: @Symbol1 It might be better to suggest asking a new question since this question was not asked by the person who posted this answer.

Comment: @cfr Sorry I did not see that is you. This answer seems like a self-answering... So, dear Dave Rosoff, would you like to ask a new problem about your situation?

Comment: @Symbol1 I was actually the person who asked the original question that Dave links to in this answer. cfr's question is a more general version of my more specific question about `knitr` and `arara`. Perhaps this would be more appropriate as an answer to my question? I'm not sure.