# 1.5e-10 style scientific notation looks ugly in LaTeX math mode. How can I format it (kerning, etc) more nicely?

Tags: math-mode, kerning

I've noticed that e-style (for example, 1.5e-10) scientific notation does not look especially nice in Latex math mode:

[image]

(code used to generate  the above image: `$1.5e-10$`)

In particular, the width and kerning of the negative sign is totally off. Is there any way to specifically fix the issues with the negative sign?

#### My LaTeX code:

Here's the complete code, including packages, for the above image:

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
$1.5e-10$
\end{document}
```

I've also run into the exact same kerning issues with MathJax (via the markdown editor in IPython Notebook. Notebook sets MathJax up automatically, so no idea what packages they use).

#### Context: floating point numbers and numerical programming

For context, when I originally asked this question I was writing a tutorial about the mathematics of stochastic simulation, with the goal of teaching people how to implement their own simulations in Python. This particular notation (`<significand>e[<sign>]<exponent>`) is relevant since it's how you write a floating point literal (ie a symbol that the Python interpreter understands as representing a particular floating point number). The `<signficand>*<base>^<exponent>` notation and its prettier variants are less appropriate, since Python (and many other languages) don't recognize it.

Comment: You can, of course, typeset however you like, but I have to add this note: This is _not_ scientific notation, but "calculator-ese", as one of my former professors put it. In my mind, its only place in typeset work is in typesetting computer/calculator input codes where `1.5e-10` is the way to present this number to the computer/calculator. In which case, it would appear in a monospaced font (not math mode), where the supposed kerning problems do not appear.

Comment: @PaulGessler +1 but don't forget sometimes you need to represent text-mode *output* exactly as well.

Comment: Treating it as the input/output of a computer/calculator I'd set it in a monospaced font rather than as maths (in the way many software books do).  If I was doing this a lot, and *making some assumptions about what else I'd be writing in the same document*, I'd probably use the `listings` package, though it's overkill just for a single example.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's not ugly, but exactly what's expected. If you type

```
$2x-10$
```

then you expect that there is some space around the minus sign, because it denotes an operation. When you type `$1e-10$`, TeX interprets it in exactly the same way, because it can't read your mind: the two expressions are formally the same, only two symbols are different.

If you want that an expression that's normally interpreted as a polynomial should be treated in a different way, then you have to properly mark it.

One solution might be

```
$1\mathrm{e}{-10}$
```

because in this case the braces around `-10` tell TeX to enter a subformula and so the minus sign is initial, so not interpreted as a binary operation, but as a unary operator.

You could make a definition, such as

```
\newcommand{\expnumber}[2]{{#1}\mathrm{e}{#2}}
```

and input the number as

```
$\expnumber{1}{-10}$
```

but there's a much better alternative, the package `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}

\begin{document}

\num{1e-10}

\end{document}
```

This package offers *many* more features than just printing numbers in the desired format; consult its documentation to find them.

[image]

---

Note that `siunitx` is *not* understood by MathJax, so with it you must stick to the “hand made” solution. You can still say, in it,

```
$\def\num#1{\numx#1}\def\numx#1e#2{{#1}\mathrm{e}{#2}}$
```

and a formula such as `$\num{1e-10}$` will be printed in the way you want.

Comment: This is a really good answer, but it seems to me that you're still using the minus sign for e-10 and I think it really ought to be an intra-word dash, the minus sign is too long. To be honest, I think I probably wouldn't even use math mode, text mode seems more appropriate, especially as the notation is surely for situations in which proper mathematical typesetting cannot be achieved

Comment: @Au101 It's a minus sign; the hyphen is definitely wrong.

Comment: Is it? Fair enough, I'd never have thought it :)

Comment: This is not *exactly* what I wanted (I sort of agree with @Au101 about the length of the minus sign), but I'd bet it's the actually correct answer. Thanks especially for the MathJax version.

Comment: @tel I believe you've been too much influenced by the bad typesetting obtained with word processors by uncaring authors: a hyphen can never be interpreted as a minus sign. When I see “1e-10” (with a hyphen) I get, at the least, goosebumps.

Comment: There are two kinds of minus signs: subtraction and negative.  I think negative signs can probably afford to be smaller than subtraction signs.  To back me up, I call on the typography of my TI-30 calculator.  The negative sign is clearly shorter there.  As for how to typeset: 1.5e--10

Comment: @Mark Never heard about any difference between the subtraction and negative signs. Well, I *know* somebody distinguishes between them, but just for didactical reasons I don't agree with.

Comment: @egreg -- I'm *sure* you're familiar with the "negative" minus, just that it's usually referred to as a "unary" minus.

Comment: @barbarabeeton What I meant is that somebody uses the minus sign for denoting subtraction and uses a raised and shorter minus sign to signify something that doesn't even qualify as a unary operator, but is part of the number (and there's an accompanying small + for positive numbers). I dislike this very much. The “unary” minus is well known to me, of course.

Comment: @egreg -- Ah, okay.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 43):

Take a look at the `siunitx` package. This is helpful for typesetting units and unitless numbers (among many other things). This works in text mode as well as math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Number only: \num{1e-10}

Number with units: \SI{1e-10}{\meter\per\second}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By adding `\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}` to the preamble, one gets `1e-10` in the required way.

Comment: @erik that looks very nice, but what I really want to know is if there's a way to format the e-style notation nicely. Knowing how to do the alternative 1x10^-10 style doesn't really help me. Any ideas?

Comment: @tel I see. I didn't realize you specifically wanted to keep the 'e' notation. egreg's comment (and answer) offer an alternative, but the typesetting may not be what you want.

Comment: 2 x 10^3 is nice, but 1 x 10^3 is verbose compared to just 10^3.  To get that, use the nonintuitive invocation `\num{e3}`.

Comment: Man this looks so beautiful. I love LaTeX, even after being out of uni for years. :)

Comment: How can I produce "10^-10 m s^-1" instead of "1x10^-10 m s^-1 using `\SI{1e-10}{\meter\per\second}` ?

Comment: @Gagik just use `\SI{e-10}{\meter\per\second}`

Comment: @erik the outcome is still `1x10^-10`. I wanna get rid of the `1x`. This is the package I am using `\usepackage[detect-all,load-configurations=si-abbr]{siunitx}` and `\sisetup{range-units=single,range-phrase=\,--\,,separate-uncertainty=true}`.

Comment: @Gagik You should remove the leading 1. `\SI{1e-10}{\meter\per\second}` will show the `1x`, whereas `\SI{e-10}{\meter\per\second}` should not.

Comment: @erik It works in a different document but not in the one I want to. Apparently somewhere in the macros there is a conflict between the `siunitx` and some other package or it is just a bug.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a really simple solution, not using any extra packages and looks just fine, in my opinion:

```
$9.54\text{e-}7$
```

That is, you're writing the "e-" part in normal text.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\scnum}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{e}}m }
 {\scnumaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\scnumaux}{ m m }
 {#1\,\mathrm{e}{#2}}

\begin{document} 

$\hbar\approx\scnum{6.626e-34} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I approved the edit since according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant the h-bar (h/2pi) is 1.054571800(13)×10−34 J⋅s. But that is not importing regarding the LaTeX problem :).

Comment: @DrManuel Kuehner: As  I'm only a poor mathematician ;-), it appears I confused the  Planck constant (*h*) and the Planck-Dirac constant (*ℏ*). I've fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately, too much space around the minus.  It's *not* being subtracted from "6.626e".

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's right. I wonder why  I inserted a thin space… 'Tis fixed. Thank you for pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

I use `$5.67\times 10^{-8}$`, and I don't have to import anything.

[image]

Comment: The idea behind `siunitx` is that with the same input `\num{1.501e-8}` you can get a variety of outputs. If you have a few of such numeric specifications, it's not a big deal. But if the copy editors of the journal you're submitting a paper to tell you that “we want 1.501e-8”, you'll thank yourself of having used `\num`: just change an option in the preamble, *et voilà*, the copy editor's request has been accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind process `.Rnw` files (`.Rtex` files in Overleaf)  with R and  [knitr](https://yihui.org/knitr/), instead of pure LaTeX files (`.tex`), to produce the correct scientific notation is as simple as declare that *1.5e-10*  is  a *S  expression* (i.e., a notation for nested list, well, i.e., an object that R language can manage).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\Sexpr{1.5e-10}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: mwe]

---

N.B.: See [How to build Knitr document from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line) if you do not want use  Overleaf on-line or RStudio off-line (recommended) to compile this.

Comment: You missed the whole point of the question. I want to know specifically how to format "1.5e-10" nicely as-is, not how to auto-convert it to a different notation

Comment: Sorry, I thinked  that the whole point  was not the kerning of the minus sign, but a  scientific notation, that as pointed in the comments, is not this "calculator notation",  but if you want one more solution in this sense, `$1\mbox{e$-$}10$` or `$1\mbox{e\ensuremath-}10$` will produce exactly the same output that solutions using  `\mathrm` or `siunitx`package.